# Why does commenting cause me to fail a review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was recently given this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5242918) for [Convariance with C# Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24286912).

The question asked for two things:

1. Why the `as` conversion didn't work
2. And how to achieve the desired effect

As someone who frequents the C# tag, I knew the reason & solution the question was asking for. Therefore, I decided that I would comment with the answer to #1 and do a quick search for an SO question to #2. The comment I had in mind would've looked something like this:

> `nonTyped` returns null because `as` returns null for an invalid
>   cast. As for how to achieve what you want, take a look at [some SO question].

The question, however, turned out to be an audit, and I had failed it for attempting to add a comment. Am I wrong in trying to add a comment that would be helpful to the question asker? Why is a comment viewed as an action made for bad posts? Is this really correct behavior? And am I not supposed to provide helpful comments at all during reviews?

[image: Failed audit]

Furthermore, to my astonishment, **I was given a ban from reviewing**, even though this is, if I recall correctly, only my second failed audit, out of 500+ reviews completed (now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure I failed the first one for trying to comment, too). Why? Doesn't the system allow for small margins of error on both ends (user & system)?

[image: Review ban]

Comment: Google brought me here can you link to the dupe if you close as dupe.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail, the link is on top of the question. Still here is another one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment