# Why does just clicking EDIT fail review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have found similar questions asking [Why does commenting cause me to fail a review audit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262919/why-does-commenting-cause-me-to-fail-a-review-audit?rq=1) and [Review audit failed after just clicking "add comment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment). Here is what I've asked:

I was reviewing a low-quality answer (now deleted):
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6030936

I skimmed the answer and thought it was basically saying "I have a similar issue" (in about 2 lines), "I did something that may have solved the problem" (in one line), and something else polite (in one line). 
(Note: This is out of my memory and turns out the match the actual deleted answer which wasn't visible to me until revealed in one of the answers here by a high-rep user below).

The rejecting comment under that answer says "If you have a different question, then etc.". I think this is clearly a misunderstanding on the commentator's part that the person answering was asking another question rather than trying to answer. I clicked "EDIT", with an intention to help the guy by probably reorganizing the answer and moving the potential solution line upfront, and probably fix other things upon closer look. I have seen many cases where an good answer is dismissed as a comment or question just because it contains a question mark to confirm something, and helped to improve answers by removing that misunderstanding.

My question is about the timing of audit, I was banned immediately from reviewing the moment I clicked "EDIT" button, without knowing what I was going to edit.

I EDIT and cancel about half the time, depending on whether the question/answer can be salvaged eventually. Now as with the other complaints referenced at the top of the question, the automated system inferred my intention and concluded that I must eventually submit the EDIT after inspection. That's part I of my question. Is that reasonable?

Part II of my question is that I found no way to flag an automated audit result, other than posting it on a case-by-case basis here at the meta.

Part III of my question is that quite often, the post (question/answer) that fail you in audit is deleted (as is with my case) so that you don't have a chance to review your issues or errors without going through the trouble of raising a question at meta.

I don't think the above features are reasonable, regardless of whether in my specific case the link in the solution is actually a spam or a good link as in the other answers, and whether and what I was going to commit in the edit.

I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Re: your PS, this isn't an answer to a deleted question. It's a deleted answer to a question.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the P.S. now it's less relevant. But in any case, the evidence used for banning me isn't visible to me, be it a deleted question or answer. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think it's kind of wrong that clicking edit would immediately block you - I like to use edit to view the targets of links and such.

Answer (score 11):

The post was a *spamvertisement*; it promoted a third-party website:

> I needed to extract contacts from my email regularly and I tired using many products and following are the issues with them: 1. None of them are free 2. They ask for a lot of money 3. Provides a very limited solutions in the basic version.
>
> I found one more option (http://www.example.com/spamvertised) which looks very promising and its completely free.
>
> Let me know if any one has a better option.

I redacted the target site; this is blatant spam. It tries to sell you a product (a 'free' website that uses advertising to make money), disguised as a recommendation from a 'genuine user'. The account was deleted, making it likely a moderator destroyed the account for more such posts.

Pokechu22's comment showed that you were not the only one having missed that this was spam:

> Welcome to Stack overflow. We aren't a normal forum. Rather than posting your question as an answer, you should ask it as a new question and link back to this existing question if it provides context.

The post was deleted as spam (automatically, after receiving at least 6 spam flags), and that made it eligible for use in audits. You do need to be on your guard for such posts, as you *are* acting as one of the lines of defence against spammers. We don't want such content on our site.

Comment: Part of what made me think that was valid was that there are several other answers that were software recommendations.  I ended up flagging it as `Not an answer`, though.  In the future, I'll make sure to check the links and see if it's actually valid software.

Comment: @Pokechu22: always be very suspicious of these posts; at best ask the author about their affiliation with the site; for any such links you *must* disclose an affiliation. When in doubt, flag it for moderator attention (other -> explain that it looks like promotion).

Comment: Then should the other answers to that question also be flagged?

Comment: @Pokechu22 if they are providing links to external software without disclosure, perhaps they should be, yes. Look at the author accounts and see if this is all they are doing, and perhaps the *question* should just be closed anyway, if it is attracting so much spam in the first place.