# Failed audit review but the counter went up

Tags: support, review-audits, badges

Today I passed 500 rep mark and I wanted to celebrate it with my first review, but strange stuff happened.

First of all, although the question was well formatted, I wanted to add a comment with a link that might be useful for the author (it wasn't and answer but was related to the topic) and I got a message, that I failed an audit because I was suppose to approve it or upvote it, and that some else already handled this.

Fair enough, let's keep helping the user and review apart.

But still my counter shows that I have one review completed and I got Custodian badge, which is kinda strange since the review was a fake, I didn't complete it (because I've never submitted that comment) and even an attempt to add it made me fail the audit.

So I'd like to know if it was intended behaviour, because from user's perspective it definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: One part of your question is discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment.

Comment: I have no problem with that part. Keeping "review" part away from "helping" part does seem strange on this site, but ok, if everyone else agree that it's a good idea then I'm not complaining. What I don't understand is why I got a badge while I didn't deserve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations!

You now have review privileges, which put you in a crucial place to help the community. As a new reviewer, you are first taught how to help new users in the [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) review queues.

The object of these queues is to introduce new users to the moderation policies of this site and to help them gain some footing to begin their journey on Stack Overflow. Your decisions in these queues are binding: that is, whatever decision you make is final and no other reviewers will come across it in the queue.

### The First Posts Queue

Never posted a question or answer before? Once you do, your question heads here. All first posters' questions and answers come to this queue and you have a few options:

- **No Action Needed**: This post is acceptable and nothing needs to be done to improve it (honestly, you shouldn't need this too often in this queue).
- **Skip**: Not sure about this post? Not familiar with the discussed technologies? Skip it. If you review this post improperly, *no other reviewer will see it*, so it is imperative that you take the proper measures to help new users learn.
- **Vote Up/Down**: These should be familiar to you by now. In review, though, they become even more important tools: use them with care because they can mean a lot to new users who may not understand the meaning of voting and freak out when they see a negative score on their post (this doesn't mean upvote it to make them feel better- consider pointing them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)).
- **Flag**: You should also be familiar with flagging by now, as it is a great tool to bring a post to the attention of the community. Flags should only be used to indicate issues of moderation, not technical inaccuracy. Depending on the flag type, you may propel the post into a different queue for review by higher-rep users or bring it directly to a moderator's attention: be careful when using these, but don't hesitate if they are necessary. See [Privilege: Flag Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- **Edit**: Anyone can edit: you've had this privilege since you've had your account. Posts from new users are often in need of some fixing-up for grammar and formatting, so this is also a great tool for reviewing. Make sure your edits are substantial enough to be approved via the [Suggested Edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), which is where your edits go for approval if you have under 2000 reputation at the time of the edit. When you reach 2000 rep, your edits do not need to be approved and are applied instantly, so you do not need to worry about how substantial your edits are, but you should still make sure to fix all issues in the post.
- **Comment**: Commenting in a review queue takes on a different meaning, as you've found out. Comments should be used to request clarification from the author, not to provide answers or resources. Commenting counts as a review action, so *only* comment for the purpose of the latter if you've already completed another review action (vote, edit, or flag). If there's no action needed or you feel you should skip it, open the post in another tab and perform the appropriate action.

Remember: this queue can make or break new users, and it is often looked down upon since it is one of the first queues opened to new reviewers and thus has a poor track record for reviews, but it is important nevertheless. Be careful.

### The Late Answers Queue

Your tools are the same as above, but you will likely not find yourself here as often. There are fewer posts in this queue because new users answer old posts less often then they post answers to new questions and ask their own questions (obviously). However, many users register after finding a post from Google solely to upvote it (only to find out that 25 rep is needed to do so). They will sometimes, finding that they also cannot comment, post an *answer* asking for help or thanking the answerer who fixed their problem.

The only answers that you will find yourself giving the go-ahead for are those that are a true answer to the question. These answers will almost always be from those same people who found a post from Google, but they've found a solution themselves and decide to post it. Despite their good intentions, these types of answers could still use some fixing up via editing/commenting.

New answers to old questions are also sometimes a target for spam, so watch out for that and be prepared to flag as necessary. Your most common tools in this queue will likely be editing and non-answer/spam flags.

Review audits are designed to tell whether you are *paying attention*. If you have the capacity to check the vote counts and make an informed review, you are already doing more than those whom audits are designed to catch.

These audits are automatically determined by the system, which often leads to disagreements about their correctness (if you ever are concerned about the validity of an audit, just bring it up here on Meta). There are two types: positive and negative, categorized by the type of review action you are expected to take.

Positive audits are questions/answers that the system has found to have high vote counts and a positive response (although sometimes that could be for the wrong reason, which is what leads to the disagreements). You are expected to either upvote or press the <kbd>**No Action Needed**</kbd> button on these posts.

Negative audits have low vote counts and may have been flagged. On these, you are expected to comment, edit, flag, or downvote (or close vote once you reach 3k rep).

Your audit fell into the former category, so a comment (which, again, is used to request clarification from the author) was an inappropriate action.

In both cases, the posts have already been handled (*appropriately* is what the audit message says, but that's not always the case) and they are just there to test you.

Skipping an audit does...just that: it skips it. It is neither a positive nor a negative action, and that is by design: you should be skipping posts that you are unsure about.

---

Alright: now that that's out of the way, let me address your question.

All audits count as reviews, both in your history and in your review count for the day (20 max) despite the fact that they have no actual effect on the post itself. Why that is is addressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197875/why-do-audits-count-toward-the-maximum-number-of-reviews-in-a-queue/197877#197877) by [animuson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson), a Stack Overflow moderator.

I also recommend taking a look at the [audits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) on Meta.SE.

Comment: Actually animuson's post provides a proof that it's a bug. Allow me to quote: "Because audits also count towards your review stats for badges as an action `(assuming you passed)`." I failed the audit and I still got the badge.

Comment: @DarthHunterix It's stated in a way that makes it a given. He goes on to explain how that fits into the context of SE.

Comment: No, he talks about the daily limit. I see no reason why daily limit of reviews made and number of total reviews should be the same number. Failed audits should count to the daily limit, as he explains, but not for the badges.

Comment: @DarthHunterix There must be some post somewhere that I can't find, but this is definitely the intended behavior: audits count as reviews even though your actions don't apply.

Comment: Ok, in I'll take your word for it :) Still, I find it a bit illogical.

Comment: @DarthHunterix Yes: it's a bit strange, but there's either some reasoning behind it or it's not a very high priority fix.

Comment: @DarthHunterix That answer on Meta.SE is worded a bit strangely, but if you read through it again, you'll see that what animuson is saying is that count isn't granular: that is, the fact that audits count as review actions is definite (for whatever reason) and if you were to not count them toward the daily limit, yo could rack up reviews without a limit. That's still not an answer to your question, but his tone in affirming that audits count toward badge counts makes me suspect that it has been laid out somewhere (that I can't find) why they count toward the counts.

Comment: Yes and I agree, that all reviews should count to the daily limit for precisely those reasons. But it is not a daily limit we are talking about, it's overall counter.

Comment: @DarthHunterix That's part of the problem: if you keep one, the other has to stay as well, and I wouldn't expect SE to get rid of both of them any time soon.

Comment: But why can't one be incremented and the other not in case of failed audit?

Comment: @DarthHunterix If you increment the one that counts toward the daily limit without the full count, then it doesn't seem fair (you waste a review and it doesn't count). If you flip those around, you run into the problem described by animuson. If you can put together a [tag:feature-request] on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com), you might gain some traction. The worst-case scenario is that it's marked a duplicate or declined and you find the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I don't see how not counting a failed review is unfair and that's the reason for the whole discussion :) Like I said before, if I'm the only one to see it as a problem then it's not worth anyone's time. I just thought it just doesn't look as intended behaviour so I reported a bug.

Comment: @DarthHunterix That's the right thing to do. This is just my opinion on it and, as far as I know, it's intended to be that way. What I meant by unfair was that it counted toward your daily limit but not your overall count, so it's a waste of a review: it lessens the number you can do per day without counting for anything.

Comment: I guess we've reached the point when the discussion reached deep levels of philosophy and the basic concept of "what is fair", so there is no actual point in continuing it. Thanks for all your effort and comments.

Comment: @DarthHunterix No problem: I'm glad it was of use to you.