# How to appeal a review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So I just got hit with a no pass on a review on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5453499).

I agree that it's probably not a 50-upvote answer, but it doesn't seem to be horrible either, especially given that the other two answers on the question (which I did take the time to check) didn't seem particularly helpful either, and had been neither upvoted nor accepted.

I don't think a fairly well written answer that seems to add information to the issue for an old unanswered question should be tagged as "very low quality".

Should I appeal this audit failure? If so, how?

P.S. There are a bunch of questions very similar to mine, all pointing to various other snags people seem to have with the audit process. This kind of makes me feel like I'm posting a repeat question, but the fact is none of those other questions have particularly satisfying answers so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't really *appeal* an audit failure: you can post it here with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) tags and ask for community input on a particular audit. **Add details about why you think the post shouldn't be used as an audit and why you think that your review was justified.** We'll discuss it and provide our opinions on whether the audit is appropriate.

As these audits [are automatically selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection), you're going to run into a few edge cases that may seem like they could go either way. If you think that an audit that requires a negative action is okay, then go to the original post (if it still exists) and upvote it. If an audit that requires a positive action seems poor to you, go to the original and downvote it. That is, take a counteraction to ensure that the audit is no longer used.

Audits are often subjective, but I think that, in this case, the audit was justified. You should have been on alert the second you saw the first sentence:

> I just ran into the same issue while going through the same book.

Questions that start like that almost always end in another question; if the "answer" does not answer the question, it should be flagged as "Not an answer."

I get it: you were probably floating along through the queue and a large block of text that doesn't immediately appear to be spam probably seems like it's okay (especially since most late answers from new users are one-line and link-only). It happens to all of us, but in this case, the audit did its job: you likely weren't paying attention, and that can be dangerous in these queues because they're meant to help new users learn how to use the site.

I'd recommend taking a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266108/3366929) that I wrote for new reviewers to get an idea of what you should look out for in the First Posts and Late Answers queues.

Comment: That's just the thing, I'd understand it if that's what happened. But it's not. I read the answer carefully, and I read the question itself with some care, even spent some time pondering the previously existing answers. I hold that I very much *was* paying attention.

Comment: "I just ran into the same issue" could be followed by a resolution. Don't get triggered by single sentences.

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't want to be too rash there: I don't literally mean flag it the second you see that answer. I meant *be on alert* if you see a sentence like that; I'll revise that part.

Comment: @JoãoMendes Reading through the post, I can understand why you may have chosen `No Action Needed`, but you **Reviewed** the post, so you must have upvoted it, which isn't appropriate: at the very least, it could have used some grammar editing/formatting, but what really should have struck you is that, throughout the entire answer, the poster does not actually address the question directly. The answer gives details about the poster's case and possible reasons why the problem *could* have occurred, but s/he does not address the post directly, which is an issue.

Comment: @JoãoMendes That answer should be condensed into a comment, and you'll find that many new users choose to write answers with commentary because they do not yet have the ability to comment.

Comment: @JoãoMendes Your [audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5453499) says **Reviewed**, which means you must have done something. I assumed that it was an upvote because that's the only "positive" action other than **No Action Needed**. For you to have failed the negative audit, you must have taken a positive action. Had you clicked **No Action Needed**, the audit would have said that.

Comment: Something seriously obscure is going on. When I click on it now, it says Review audit passed 3 hours ago...

Comment: @JoãoMendes Might you have performed an action like a comment or edit and *passed* the audit?