# Incorrectly failed first post review audit because of a *positive* comment on a good answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing the First Posts queue I was presented [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10202780). It seemed like a very good question for which I wanted to compliment the first poster.

I added a positive comment that also contained a hint to an answer, i.e. a link to the Wikipedia's article on the halting problem and briefly mentioning how it relates to the dead code detection problem the user was asking about. I also intented to upvote the question right after.

To my unpleasant surprise, however, the system showed me the infamous *"STOP! Look and listen!"* screen for the failed audit as soon as I submitted the comment, without giving me a chance to finish my review. This also resulted in a temporary review ban because of a few other recent mistakes on my part (e.g. approving link-only answers - I learned my lesson).

After some research (e.g. found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits)), it became clear to me that this is indeed a flaw in the system, and that simply posting a comment on a good post should not have triggered the ban.

Now, my question is - can this be somehow manually reversed? Or is just something that should be sucked up and accepted as a feature of the system?

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267622/5040035), an appeal is not possible, but one can open a question labeled as  [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) for the community's input on this, which I now did.

---

**Edit:** Just to be clear, the [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) is IMO not a duplicate - the linked question asks whether the observed system behavior should be changed (FWIW - I also referred to it in my own question), while I'm asking whether the system's clear incorrect decision can somehow be reversed.

Comment: The "input" you mention in [How to appeal a review audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267618/how-to-appeal-a-review-audit) is for why you failed the audit.  Your research explains that you obviously know why you failed the audit, so appealing to meta for explanation is meaningless.  We can't change the system, we can only tell you how it works.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I initially questioned the "duplicate" resolution, because the first linked question is about _why_, not whether a bad system decision can be reversed. OTOH, now seeing the second question linked, that one makes much more sense as a possible duplicate. During the research I skimmed over its answer, but after re-reading it again now, I see that its _"you can post it here"_ part actually refers to discussing the _why_, which I already had figured out. Sorry for the fuss.