# How can I dispute a wrong audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers, specific-audit

I had to [review an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28601499) to the following question:

[VSCode - Python - List Index Limit Max 300 - Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324745/vscode-python-list-index-limit-max-300-debugger/66615823#66615823)

> I have a list contains several hundred entries. I think the total size
> of the list is 3.5MB.
>
> When debugging an issue I can't seem to view any entry passed 300 and
> I see this message 'Too large to show contents. Max items to show:
> 300'
>
> Any ideas?

The answer to review was:

> Note that you can watch an index of a list : ie watch listname[1000] to show just the 1000th element

In my opinion, this is actually a rather good answer. The question is about how to see an entry with an index greater than 300 and the answer shows concisely a simple solution. It includes all needed information and it is an idea not mentioned in any other answer of that question.

The audit states:

> *This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass.*

I feel this is a rather arrogant statement, accusing me of not paying attention. In actual fact, I spent minutes, reading also all the other answers, which would not be really required for a review.

It's upsetting to be accused of *not paying attention*, when, in my maybe-not-so humble opinion, the audit's assumption *"This answer was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful"* is simply not true.

Even more upsetting is that there is no way to dispute the audit outcome. If Stack Overflow expects me to spend hours for reviewing for free, at least they could:

1. Not insult me.
2. Give me an easy way to dispute an audit.

I did spend an hour trying to find an answer on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ how to dispute an audit. All I found was answers by some normal users like me, discussing if the audit was right or wrong. But I could not find anywhere how to dispute an audit.

If Stack Overflow feels it is ok to insult its reviewers and doesn't provide an **easy** way to dispute wrong audits, I would not be surprised if fewer and fewer are willing to do reviewing. I, at least, am done reviewing after this frustrating experience for the day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: I sympathize with your feelings, but don't understand what you mean by *dispute*. Did you get a ban following this audit? If not, learn the best you can from this audit, and simply move on

Comment: Please, leave out all the bits about "arrogance", "accusations", and "insulting reviewers". It's just a very naive system doing its job. Instead of taking it personally, see if there isn't something to learn (or to fix) from this experience.

Comment: I think users start out reviewing as soon as they get the new (duty?) privilege. Some have somewhat disappointing experiences and some of those just stop reviewing. That's perfectly fine. I'm personally disappointed that the entire process doesn't properly onboard new users.

Comment: [Worth reading, if you haven't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/1426539). (Or re-areading, if you have)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to appeal a review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267618/how-to-appeal-a-review-audit) Basically this says to open a Meta question, but it lays out a clear guide for how to structure the question. It does not include whining and rage quitting as far as I can see.

Comment: You failed the audit since you failed to identify an answer that had already been deleted due to it being extremely low quality. I see nothing wrong with that review, if your opening the question in another tag, it’s obviously a review audit (most audits are).  The automatic commentary saying it didn’t answer the question, with a link to a review, should prevented you from choosing the option you chose

Comment: I am confused. You say "In actual fact, I spent minutes, reading also all the other answers, which would not be really required for a review." – at the moment your review is 1 hour old and the answer was deleted 9 days ago. Did you not realise the answer was deleted, or did you realise it and still think the answer was okay?

Comment: @SecurityHound The Answer isn't a "Not an Answer". The Low Quality Posts queue is not suppose to do anything other than verifying/validating a ["Not an Answer"-flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). It's not a queue to decide the technical quality of the Answer in any way. That people use it to get rid of stuff without having the privilege to actually delete wrong Answers doesn't make it right.

Comment: @Scratte this review audit wasn't on the LQP queue. Was on the LA queue. It's usually good to get your facts right before posting a rant.

Comment: @yivi I know. But the link SecurityHound refers to is to the Low Quality Posts queue. Either way, the actions are suppose to be similar. 'Is it or is it not a "Not an Answer"?'

Comment: No, @Scratte, the actions not "supposed to be similar". LA queue is a much more subtle queue. Answers are not simply judged to be or not to be "an answer".

Comment: @yivi There's the option to edit in both. Either of the queue is making a determination as to whether the post is to be kept or not kept on the site. Late Answers just sends it along to the Low Quality Posts if it's flagged. While it's possible to pass the audit in Late Answers just by downvoting the post, the fact that the post was deleted indicate that the Late Answer response in case of an actual review would have been to flag it.

Comment: No, @Scratte, one could have passed the LA review by other actions than flagging. Conflating these things does not help. This is a question about a review-audit in the LA queue, the appropriate actions **there** are what's relevant. The problem here was choosing "No Action Needed" for this specific audit.

Comment: @yivi Those are downvote, edit or flag to pass this audit. I think commenting used to make one pass it too, but if I recall that was removed recently. As far as I see it, this post is about what to do when you think the audit is wrong. Not about how to pass or fail the audit. If it had been an actual review, not an audit, the result of the review should not just be a downvote and then "I'm Done", if the post is be removed, right?

Comment: @Scratte - I never said it wasn’t an answer.  I said it was low quality, had been deleted by review, my comment was about the audit being obviously an audit.  I get what this question is about, and perhaps it serves a purpose, but the audit in this case is a legitimate audit.  3/4 of the reviewers of the answer have more than 10K reputation on SO. One was 50,000 another 90,000

Comment: Frankly, this is a terrible audit, and arguably shouldn't have been deleted by LQP in the first place.  [Two of the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28524830) voted "Looks OK." It may be a mediocre answer (watching _one_ additional element isn't super useful), but it's an answer, and it adds something to the question.

Comment: @JeanneDark: No, that answer does not answer my question about "How to dispute a wrong audit?". I read it before posting my question and to be honest, I found the 2 answers there rather confusing. Maybe because I am reviewing today for the first time ?

Comment: @yivi No, that answer does not answer my suggestion "How to dispute a wrong audit?" As most other comments don't address my suggest at all.

Comment: @SecurityHound I see. Sorry about that. You're right that it's fairly easy to see that it was indeed an audit just by looking at the comments and clicking through to see what the outcome was. I kind of got caught up with what *I think* is the root of this post, as in "The answer should have been allowed to stay and the audit itself is wrong about what should be done here".

Comment: @RyanM - It was an answer that was deleted by users with 50,000, 90,000, and 11,000 reputation.  If those users are deleting an answer that shouldn't have been deleted something should be done to signal to those users that is the case.  However, I disagree, the answer was terrible.  *It read like a comment.*

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, this is a mediocre audit at best, and arguably shouldn't have been deleted by LQP in the first place. [Two of the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28524830) voted "Looks OK." It may be a mediocre answer (watching *one* additional element isn't super useful), but it's an answer, and it adds something to the question.

That said..."No action needed" isn't exactly correct.  This is Late Answers, so the actions that should be taken are broader than just a yes/no on whether the post should stay at all.  The biggest issue I see is that it contains code (`listname[1000]`) that isn't code-formatted in the post.  That should have been edited to show a new user how to properly format their posts.  If we're really nitpicking, "ie" should be "i.e.," as well.

Comment: Agreed. To add on that, it also really calls for a comment (Something like "your answer is very broad and vague, try to add some details"), which I believe would be considered as passing the audit

Comment: I also want to point out that the answer is **wrong**. `listname[1000]` is actually going to get the 1001st element due to Python indexes starting at 0.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."

Comment: The I formatted code was the biggest reason I considered that a horrible answer beyond the fact it was also an incorrect answer.  Which is probably the reason it was deleted.

Comment: Let's assume the Answer had not been deleted, but was still used in an audit. Wouldn't any other action apart from upvoting → "I'm Done" or "No Actions Needed" have failed them in that audit? Meaning pressing "edit" (along with downvoting or flagging) would have failed them?

Comment: @Scratte depends on what moderation was performed in reality. Will there ever be an audit on an answer which was not in fact deleted I wonder?

Comment: @Gimby Interestingly.. I can't find a single of my own audit reviews in Late Answers, where the Answer hadn't been deleted. That is a little disturbing.