# Am I expected to participate in the edit review process once I reach 2K rep?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

A few days ago, I reached 2K rep on SO. This unlocked the review queue for me. however, there are several issues I have with this:

1. I'm getting edit reviews for languages that I'm not at all familiar with and where I have no idea how accurate the edits are.
2. I have less than 2 years of experience across all languages, basically a Junior profile. I have severe doubts that I am qualified to do any edit reviews.
3. I have no interest in doing any edit reviews. I get that this is quite controversial, but I use SO to look for answers for problems I have and occasionally to help other people with their problems by answering their problems. I personally don't think that reviewing edits fits in that usage profile.
4. I am not yet familiar enough with the SO editing rules to confidently approve or reject reviews.

These issues can obviously fix themselves over time, but at this point in time, I have no interest at all in doing edit reviews, nor do I think it is in the best interest of SO that I am doing them due to my lack of experience. A few moments ago, I did my first edit review queue and I just skipped all the edits because of the above reasons.

Obviously, I want to keep using SO and follow the rules while doing so, but I'd rather do this without edit reviews for now. Is this an option?

---

After a few days of cautiously trying out the edit review queue, I feel a bit more comfortable doing this. As stated, most of the edits are simple grammar cleanups, which I think I can handle.

I think part of the issue was that I didn't really have a good idea how to handle this queue, what was expected of me. After a few approvals, rejections and skips, I think I can handle this somewhat. It was just somewhat unexpected to suddenly see this pop up.

Comment: As there is no obligation to do so, I do suggest to take a look at the review queue every once in a while. It isn't only about contributing, you may also get something out of it, especially as a junior dev. Many do's and don'ts, reading other peoples code, and reading comments from experienced devs

Comment: Do you think you'd be more inclined to do reviews if there was a review [training process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289871/4014959)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can participate, but it's not "expected".

If you do and you don't feel you are qualified to do any particular review just click on the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button to take you onto the next one and leave that one for someone else.

Answer (score 47):

Reviewing is not mandatory, but it *is* helpful!

In particular suggested edits are helpful because they are intended for the community to make questions and answers more helpful, easier to understand, and higher quality.

Many suggested edits simply involve improving English spelling and grammar, correcting code formatting, updating broken links, and the like, and don't require a lot of experience. You can also always Skip a review you aren't sure about.

To make the review queues easier to deal with, you can filter using up to three tags. For instance you could specify [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as your tags, and only review questions about those topics.

[image: Review Filter]

Stack Overflow is moderated by the community, and this is your first chance to participate. You'll unlock further moderation privileges as you continue to gain reputation. Give it another go with filters in place, and I think you'll find suggested edits much more pleasant.

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned, you're not *expected* to participate within this privilege.

> 1. I'm getting edit reviews for languages that I'm not at all familiar with and where I have no idea how accurate the edits are.

There's the possibility to filter the review queues for certain tags IIRC. I never got very familiar using these anyway.

> 2. I have less than 2 years of experience across all languages, basically a Junior profile. I have severe doubts that I am qualified to do any edit reviews.

There's enough edits just qualifying invalid besides of any language related peculiarities. So there's still enough scope you can participate by judging.

> 3. I have no interest in doing any edit reviews. I get that this is quite controversial, but I use SO to look for answers for problems I have and occasionally to help other people with their problems by answering their problems. I personally don't think that reviewing edits fits in that usage profile.

Then just leave it. As mentioned, you're no way *being expected* to participate.

> 4. I am not yet familiar enough with the SO editing rules to confidently approve or reject reviews.

As mentioned for point 2., there's still enough judging skills we could (should) expect from you to detect *vandalized* or *minor* edits, that aren't helpful to improve a question.

Answer (score 18):

Reviewing is voluntary; you are not obliged to go to the review queues if you don't want to.

Answer (score 18):

My impression is that doing nothing, in any context, on Stack Overflow is absolutely fine: not answering, not asking a question, not voting, not commenting, and not helping in the review queues. Anything more than nothing, as long as it adheres to the rules, is a bonus.

(The possible exception I can think of is not doing something that you explicitly agreed to do, such as be a moderator.)