# Are the edits of 2k rep users moderated?

Tags: support, edits

I know that if a person gets 2k reputation they can edit any post without the need for approval.

The reason behind this is that Stack Overflow considers that user is experienced and understands what makes a good edit; they're not learning any more and the community doesn't need to approve. But, sometimes some people make edits which are not relevant or harm the post/owner.

I saw one [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290686/am-i-expected-to-participate-in-the-edit-review-process-once-i-reach-2k-rep?cb=1) in which a user stated that, *"I'm getting edit reviews for languages that I'm not at all familiar with and where I have no idea how accurate the edits are."* Someone's editing a post when they don't have much of an idea about how to do so.

Does the community moderate edits in this situation?

Comment: When that happens, there's a good chance the edit gets rolled back. That's why edits push a question up on the front page.

Comment: Do you know what an edit war is? : ) But in all seriousness, a vast majority of the edits from 2k+ users are good. The fact that there is less oversight is generally OK because they/we don't need it.

Comment: To be fair, that's not an accurate depiction of what the user you quoted was saying. They're talking about *reviewing* edits they're not familiar with. They aren't running around editing posts in ignorance.

Comment: *"they're not learning any more"* not necessarily

Comment: The person you quote specifically states in their question _"I did my first edit review queue and I just skipped all the edits because of the above reasons"_, so they actually didn't make any edits.

Comment: Recently I saw a [user tagging jQuery tag](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22814525#22814525) to a pure JS question.. god help SO ..

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Such edits are *still* being reviewed, just less explicitly.  The edited post gets [bumped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bump/info) back to the front-page and the post owner gets a notification.

Nothing is permanent, everything can be fixed.  If such a user gives one of my posts a terminal case of Lyme disease by adding twenty back-ticks then, bam, a quick rollback is all it takes to restore health.

Comment: Instant classic: *a terminal case of Lyme disease by adding twenty back-ticks*

Comment: I am tempted to add 20 back-ticks to this answer.

Comment: Ugg... which is that 2k editor that gives Lyme disease?

Comment: I had someone edit an answer I had and just edited and added some wrong info.  I then had comments pointing this out and the history didn't show who else had edited it.  Apparently edits within a short space of time are concatenated.  It's not always easy to rollback.

Comment: An `edit` with `too` many `back-ticks` is just `as bad` as a `useless` comment`.`

Answer (score 15):

Most of the questions I come across need to be edited, this is an indication that there are *many* questions that should be edited.

Usually, users with 2K+ reputation posted many answers/questions, so their posts were corrected or they got used to formation on Stack Overflow.

In any other case, the posts can be easily rolled back by more experienced user or by OP.