# User being encouraged to insert inappropriate formatting

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Every day this week I've run into several suggested edits from the same user that do nothing but insert code formatting and occasional bold or italics where they don't belong. I keep rejecting them, but others are accepting these edits, further encouraging this user to continue to make such edits.

You can see some of these edits from the past two days [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039848), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8054590), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8054807), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039652), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039462), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039196), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039105), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8038996), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024670), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024598), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024594), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024234), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024156), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024120), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024115), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024058), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024046), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8023460), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8023241), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8022760). You get the idea.

It appears that this user is trying to farm reputation through editing. I should also point out that he has plenty of helpful edit suggestions among the not-so-helpful ones.

What can we do (that we aren't already doing) to curb this sort of behavior without discouraging helpful edits and reviews?

Comment: What does it say about me that I went and opened all 20 of those links?

Comment: It says you now have 20+ tabs open

Comment: @BoltClock Hopefully that you care enough about the integrity of the review system to edit ban that editor and review ban the reviewers accepting those edits.

Comment: @random: That number just tripled.

Comment: I ran across this user today while I was doing reviews.  I approved the first one because there was some good in it but the rest I rejected as I saw a definite pattern of unsubstantial edits.  @BoltClock I did the same thing.  I was surprised to see the tabs shrunk as much as they did

Comment: @BoltClock [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8054796) is one more for you

Comment: I like how he highlights application names using code formatting.  Quite the brilliant young man.

Comment: It looks like the user was trying get Archaeologist badge by hook or by crook as most of these posts are old and his next badge in profile is Archaeologist.

Comment: I am horrified to discover that the user in question is not the one I was thinking about.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/150515

Comment: What if we had a system where users could flag incorrectly approved suggested edits, and those edits would go into a review queue, and if the edit was decided to be harmful, the reviewers who accepted it (and  the user who suggested it) would get a similar effect to failing a review audit (a notification letting them know, and if it happens enough times, a ban)?

Comment: @NobodyNada I like that idea, but what would prevent the same error from being made in that review queue? And if we start having reviews for the reviews, where does it end?

Comment: @Brian Yeah, that's the problem.  But this queue wouldn't get as much activity as the suggested edits queue, making it less inviting to robo-review.  It could also have a high rep limit (10K/20K), but that probably wouldn't help much.

Comment: ...Is it bad that, for a moment, I thought that was me? My edits tend to be mostly fixing grammar and formatting things to look prettier, and I could well have a streak of [giving posts terminal Lyme disease](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290934/1863564) from when I fumble around SO late at night when I should have been asleep two hours ago.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Me too. Perhaps you were thinking of [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7986831) (who, to give them some credit, has apparently made great strides in the past week towards breaking their **fancy word** `library name` addiction).

Comment: @Radiodef: `I totally` **was**! Spooky!!

Comment: @BoltClock, OCD!

Comment: @Radiodef, but he **corrected** `grammer`!

Comment: I did approve two of those and I feel like I have failed SO. I will now proceed to perform the seppuku to cleanse the dishonour in my family.
It has been a pleasure serving you!
(now more seriously: sorry, I suck bananas)

Comment: I opened the first 4 edits and I would have approved all of them, too. Even after reading your post here before.

Comment: @FabianBarney See [this meta Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If people are approving inappropriate edits we can [ban them from the review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228927/165773) for a few days to consider their actions.

Though with this number of edits it might take a while.

We can also [ban the user from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/165773) for a few days too. That's a bit easier as there's only one of them.

The suggester and the approvers are all now taking a rest.

Comment: We can also ban the user from suggesting edits

Comment: @bluefeet - I forgot about that bit.

Comment: Bans All Around!!!

Comment: He appears to be at <50% accept ratio on his edits. Given the "false positives" of robo-reviewers, definitely sounds like he should take a break

Comment: Now that this has been dealt with (hopefully), what about the horrible edits themselves? I abhor this random formatting of software names and phrases. Do they all deserve a rollback? Does that need to be done manually, by "us users"?

Comment: @Jongware - I'm not going through rolling back the edits. a) it will flood the home page (at least temporarily), b) the suggester doesn't lose the rep they gained. If you want to, feel free to rollback, but do so gradually.

Comment: @bluefeet - they're all getting married?

Comment: @ChrisF: .. on second thought, in that case I like them enough to let'em be (which is a fair approximation of "I do not dislike them enough to do it").

Comment: @ChrisF Well I am going to be rolling them back, because they're all utter, utter, utter garbage. Abuse of code formatting tags is a cancer among these rep farmers and it should not be allowed to fester.

Comment: @Boann It's not a cancer it's [Lyme Disease](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290934/1947286)

Comment: @MartinJames: That's banns, not bans. Easy mistake to make, I know!

Comment: @Nathan: can we institute automatic banns here?

Comment: I wonder *if* `audits` should include ***adding** random* ***[formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206)***

Comment: @ChrisF, if you can roll the edits back more easily than we muggles can, I really think you should do so.  Never mind the disruption and the rep issue, leaving them as they are sets a bad example for future enthusiastic n00bs.

Comment: @AlanMoore - not really. I still have to visit each post, go to the history and then roll back. I have no special tools for this.

Comment: @Braiam I like that idea. Might need to include a few audits with legitimate adding of formatting as well such that reviewers are forced to tell the difference between random and legitimate formatting.

Comment: I would have approved these edits, too. Seems to be that I am not suitable for this kind of task.

Answer (score 24):

Just pick one of the posts at random and flag it, stating more of less what you've said in this meta question.  A mod can review the case to see if a user is spamming inappropriate edits, and if they're being approved, deal with both that user and those approving the edits.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the edits are about adding backticks around *Termini technici*.
It's completely common in respect to typography to highlight those terms to improve readability.

Backticks may be inappropriate here, because they should only be used for code. Are *Italics* a better choice here? As far as I know we do not have dedicated formatting rules for *termini technici*.

In my opinion these edits are not the best but they're valid. I realize that this is an uncommon opinion here.

Futhermore I feel a bit gutted that reviewers here are branded as *robo-reviewers*. This term adds offense to all the reviewers who really thought about the edit and approved it, because *robo-reviewers* implicates that only brainless people would have approved those. I don't like to be called brainless.

Since these edits are nearly all about the same issue of adding backticks a reviewer thinking in one of the two directions may come to the same conclusion for all these edits: approve all or reject all. *Reject All* seems to be the right thing to do here and the reviewers who had a different opinion got banned.

Now just think a second the other way around. Let's say the opinion of the *Approvers* with their arguments is the right thing to do here. Would you consider it fair to be banned for rejecting all these edits for the same reason that is a valid reason for rejection in your opinion?

I consider banning the reviewers in this case a disservice.

Comment: "I feel a bit gutted that reviewers here are branded as robo-reviewers." That term is used to refer to users who use scripts to do reviews for them, so they can get the review badges easily. It doesn't insult anyone who actually did the reviews themselves, because it doesn't refer to them.

Comment: @Brian: No, that term *is* used to refer to people who review mindlessly. The thought of using a script doesn't even cross the minds of the vast majority of (robo-)reviewers.

Comment: This answer brings up a good point about the reviewers who honestly thought the formatting was appropriate and accepted the edits based on their assessment. There are entire categories and cultures of people who honestly consider these edits OK, a fact that I'm *still* having a hard time accepting. It seems that this area of formatting will forever be a topic of contention in the SO community, being an international community.

Comment: @BoltClock Either way, it doesn't refer to the users who took an honest look at the suggested edit and decided that it should be approved.

Comment: @BoltClock Do we have a formatting guidelines page or canonical question anywhere? If not, I think it would be a good idea to make one.

Comment: Thanks for some backup. It's good to talk about what we consider the right way of doing things here. And sometimes this does not match your own mind. That's ok and we all should respect the "community mind". So I do and respect that such edits are not welcome here.

Banning reviewers might be necessary in certain cases, too. But in this special case here I strongly believe that most of the approvers did this with good will and not mindlessly.

Comment: @Brian: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting although the help pages don't state outright that code formatting should not be used for things that aren't code.

Comment: @BoltClock I've noticed that this use of code tags seems to be especially common among Indian users, though I've never figured out why. But due to time zones, there's often a correlation between the country of the editor and the country of the reviewers, and that can make the whims of what edits do and don't get accepted by review seem more mysterious, because it varies by time of day.

Comment: @Boann: to me it smells of thoughtless hypercorrection: 1. code must be ticked. 2. code runs on a computer: 3. therefore, code = a computer term; 4. and thus, computer term = code. 5. ergo `visual basic`, `excel`, `compiler` and, in extremis,  `keyboard` and `mouse`.

Comment: On "Backticks may be inappropriate here, because they should only be used for code.": I'd object; I'd use it for any *literal input or output* (such as error messages). Mostly because it's more readable than putting it in double-quotes. Also I think **bold** should be used for strong emphasis, not for "literal".