# Why am I review banned for a day?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When I try go to the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), a message shows

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8024115
>
> Come back tomorrow to continue reviewing.

But the link in the above message contains a suggested edit that I've approved and the edit altogether got approved. So I've actually passed that review.

Also, I've checked my recent 20 reviews or so, and I saw that I failed just one of them.

Is there something I'm missing? Why am I prevented from reviewing?

Comment: Check the users edit to which you approved.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206/user-being-encouraged-to-insert-inappropriate-formatting

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That edit was **not an audit**.

That user was [spamming the site with completely **useless** edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206/user-being-encouraged-to-insert-inappropriate-formatting) to farm reputation. That's a post from 2009 getting 'improved' by adding backticks where there are is no code, emphasis where it doesn't need it.

Please don't approve such edits. Pay attention to what the edit does, and if it is actually useful. You should have picked *no improvement whatsoever* instead of approving.

A moderator banned you and everyone else that approved too many of these edits, to make you *stop, look and listen*.