# What did I do wrong when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I went to review some posts and saw this:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8054590 Come back in
>   14 hours to continue reviewing.

I went to that link and all the reviewers did the same thing as me. Are we all wrong? What is wrong?

Comment: That particular suggestion should have been rejected - it adds no value whatsoever to the question and fails to correct a couple of grammatical mistakes. The other two reviewers should also have been given a rest for a day.

Comment: That user edited which will not make any sense. Or says not make anything in post so it become easy readable. Also check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206/user-being-encouraged-to-insert-inappropriate-formatting

Answer (score 14):

**Wierd** *formating* `does` not **MaKe** a `good` *edit*

---

You approved a trivial edit that added code formatting around the names of various applications. The backticks ( ` ) are for *code* not an application. They aren't for highlighting, formatting a word in a sentence, or anything else except code.

---

As for your ban, I suspect (but can't confirm) that a moderator issued a ban for approving such an edit. This isn't an audit failure.

Comment: huh. ok that makes sense. i thought they were just adding <code> around it to format it better. my bad

Comment: Yeah, this was not an audit failure; everyone involved in approving any of a number of similar edits was also review-banned, manually.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294207/3001761