# Meaning of "_" in `like _so_`

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

What I noticed while asking, is the guidelines located to the right side. One of the guidelines says:

> ► backtick escapes `` `like _so_` ``

I'm curious as to why does `so` needs to be in the middle of two `_`, does it mean anything? Or it is to show the italic syntax in Markdown?

Image for reference:

[image: screenshot of the How to Format sidebar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, a couple of `_` characters surrounding a string will format it with *emphasis/italic*.

But characters inside a couple of backticks will be escaped, so they will render directly instead of being interpreted with their usual meaning.

The example provided (`like _so_`), is showing you exactly that: Normally, it would be rendered "like *so*". But not within backticks.

To include backticks within backticks, you can use double backticks. Like this: `` `hello` ``.

Which was actually written like this:

```
`` `hello` ``
```

You can check the more or less complete syntax [here](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

I've used the word backticks too many times. Now it sounds weird, escaped or not.

Comment: If backticks escapes whatever is inside them, why can't I add another set of backticks inside *(like in the guidelines)*?

Comment: @Swellar Also, be aware that the guidelines are plain HTML, not rendered markdown. Which makes sense, because rendered markdown makes for a very poor guide. For example: "**This** is how you bold a string". Doesn't tell you much, does it?

Comment: Careful, [too many backticks can lead to a terminal case of Lyme disease](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290932/are-the-edits-of-2k-rep-users-moderated/290934#comment180000_290934)