# Can 2k+ rep user suggest edits?

Tags: support, edits

Is it possible for a user who has [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to make an edit suggestion.

Sometimes I feel like I understand what someone is asking but I don't want to edit the question because it would completely change it. Instead I want to make a suggestion that can be accepted/declined by the poster of the question.

Comment: I normally just make the edit and then leave a comment to inform both OP and others that the post was edited substantively and invite them to either correct what is still wrong or rollback if I missed the point.

Comment: Nope - they can't. You can suggest the idea in a comment though.

Comment: You do, it is just instantly accepted.  It still gets reviewed and it is still easy to rollback.  The OP can rollback anything, regardless of rep.  Do consider posting a comment instead, it is the most constructive way to use comments that I can think of.

Comment: You can log out and suggest an edit as an anonymous user.

Comment: @DonaldDuck you *could* but massive changes to a post are (and should be) reviewed with a fair bit of scrutiny even from registered users making the suggested edit. From an anonymous user - it doesn't stand much chance and would be a wasted effort.

Comment: @HansPassant How are my edits being reviewed when i have edit privileges?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for being able to travel in time and [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290932/are-the-edits-of-2k-rep-users-moderated/290934#290934) my previous comment :)

Comment: @Andre the OP will get a notification in their inbox and your edit bumps the post back on the homepage so others will see it.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpfull suggestions and the duplicate link