# Getting lots of [enter image description here] links in review queues

Tags: support, review-queues

I was just doing a bit of work in the review queues, and I noticed that lots of questions and answers had [enter image description here] links, with a link to a relevant image - rather then the image actually appearing inline in the post as I'd have expected.

I'm not sure if this is people not using the image insert properly, or is the image insert failing somehow? It seems to be happening a lot - so even if it's the former it looks like a problem that might somehow need addressing?

Comment: Are the posts from new users who haven’t earned the privilege to insert images yet?

Comment: Are these posts from new users who don't actually mind having the text `enter image description here` right in the middle of their question?

Comment: @user4642212 yes, that's almost certainly it; I don't know if there's any way for the system to mention to reviewers (esp. on the first posts queue) that that's normal? Otherwise I would guess it's pretty normal for people who've only just earnt reviewer privileges to have long since forgotten (if they ever knew) that new users can't insert images.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your response when it is an [image of code or an error text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)?

Comment: I think posts look more carefully constructed if a (relevant!) image appears inline, rather than when you have to click out of the post to go somewhere else to see what the image actually was. That's not quite what you're actually asking, and yes of course I understand already that a screenshot of code or text is much less useful than the code or text itself.

Comment: Or if you're asking what would I specifically do if I saw that, I'd probably put a polite comment pointing out that it wasn't as helpful as including the original text! Though I currently feel a bit like this guy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290686/ about the whole review process and the way it suddenly starts impinging on your life when you pass 1,000 rating!

Comment: @usr2564301 Out of curiosity: why were you asking?

Comment: Me, I *hate* images-of-code with a passion. It can only mean that the OP has the utmost contempt for those willing to help strangers out if OP doesn't even bother to post something we can copy. The latest development does not bode well for the next gen of programmers: *literal* screenshots, a phone-taken photo of what the OP is looking at.