# Can we have a sandbox/catalog for training triage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage

After a longer break, today I reviewed a few triage questions and I really got the impression that triage still does not work.

Going through my history page, more than 50% of the final decisions are clearly wrong. Barely any request for tool recommendation gets caught, barely any question that asks for code writing service, barely any question that does not provide a clear error message and expected behavior.

So, can we create a collection of manually curated/annotated triage questions for training? Training should be without any consequences, just a playground to get familiar with the common types of questions one will encounter. Maybe with a shiny badge in the end when you have most of them correct.

For the start it could be like 30 questions, not only annotated with a right choice, but also with a brief comment that explains why.

The access to the triage review queue could then be available after obtaining the badge.

Comment: Well, we already have audits strayed in, isn't that training enough?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I would guess `>90%` of audits are checking for obviously good and spam questions. In fact I cannot remember a single audit with a question that falls into a different category.

Comment: Why stop at triage? Having a few sample posts for people to learn from could be useful for all the review queues. I know this is something that has been brought up before, but can't find it right now.

Comment: @BradLarson, is there any way to promote a question here on meta.stackoverflow? I think it could be a good idea, but the question is already dying a slow death after only 40 views and 6 votes.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289871/practice-queues-for-review-training