# Why does this question "looks ok"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I am closing in on my gold Marshal badge and therefore am a bit more aware of what happens with my flags. I know it's dubious behaviour, maybe even close to badge hunting, but I'm not flagging things that shouldn't be flagged. Just a bit more fanatic than usual.

However I came across this post in review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588988/stop-activity-going-on-in-one-fragment-while-returning-on-onbackpressed-if-we-ar

**text for <10k readers:**

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prologic.mitini&hl=en Here is the link of my app in play store. Please have look and help. The bug is on going from home fragment to archive on button click "archive" in home fragment and playing clicking the grid but while on back press the music does not stops which i want to while i return to home fragment again.

The vague title already indicates that this probably isn't going to be a really high quality post. The text of the post is of the same level, and is asking for help without even posting the code of the app in question, just a link to google-play.

Therefore I decided to mark the question unsalvagable and flagged it as "Unclear what you are asking".

My fellow reviewers had a different opinion it seemed when I noticed my flag was disputed. Which mostly means that 3 other reviewers thought that this post "Looks ok" from what I understood. Which happened to be the case:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18120942

Now was I wrong in marking this as unsalvagable, or did the other reviewers just "robo-review" perhaps and marked this as OK?

Comment: I can smell some review bans incoming.

Comment: yeah.. voted to close as no MCVE.. OP actually wants users to go download from play store and figure out their issue.. No where near "looks ok"

Comment: It looks OK now.

Comment: Tragic, isn't it.  Biggest problem with review is that nobody lasts long enough to ever learn how to do it correctly.  They'll either fail enough audits and won't come back or get fed up with having to dig through the pile of garbage with no noticeable improvement on the site.  Last time I saw statistics (been a while), the average lifespan of a reviewer was 30 days.

Comment: [some stats are here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601) @HansPassant - per my reading vast majority drop off at less than 50 reviews (about half can't make even 10)

Comment: @HansPassant, so that would make me an out-lier?

Comment: @HansPassant IMO the problem with review is that people are thrown in at the deep end. No real introduction, no training. It's simply assumed that if one has a certain amount of rep, one is also able to judge other people's posts. This turns out not to be the case.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I Agree on that. Couldn't we make some interactive training of say 10 reviews? A bit like the audits, but without consequences, giving feedback on what was the appropriate option etc. Give it a shiny badge: "Trained reviewer". And see if we can enthausiasmise people.

Comment: @Luuklag There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149) for it. I also once brought it to the attention of one of the Community Managers (Jon Ericsson, if memory serves) who liked the idea. Haven't heard about it since though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Good thing. I bumped it with a new answer. Hopefully it draws some attention again.

Comment: There is this [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) for   the tiage queue. But I think the only way to find it is googling. There is no link to it in the tiage itself.

Comment: Can someone post an image for us lesser mortals who have less than 10k and can't see deleted posts yet?

Comment: Reviewer are let loose, No link, no tutorial, and by the time you get enough rep to review... do you really have what it takes to judge posts about technologies you might not understand completely? It's all of a skill, and it's time consuming, except if you have extremely deep knowledge

Comment: @EJoshuaS [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/47588988/stop-activity-going-on-in-one-fragment-while-returning-on-onbackpressed-if-we-ar) is a good friend to <10k rep users. Here's a bookmarklet which will open in a new tab the Google Cache for the current page's URL: `javascript:void(window.open('//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'+location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//,'')))`

Comment: Cant people <10k use the triage link to see the post? At least I can, but that might be an exception as I took place in the particular review.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289871/practice-queues-for-review-training

Comment: Checked the profile of those who lookedoked this question, and - with all due respect - I think there's a pattern - and bigger problem - here. Let's say some people spend their site time almost exclusively in the review queue (not without gaining some shiny badges), and no questions and answers come from their side for a very long time. Why? It's simple: you can (and will) be judged when you ask a question. You will be judged when you give an answer. But will your actions ever be judged when you do the review?

Comment: And if you think the training will do anything, well, think about training on giving proper answers. Will it - alone - be enough to improve their quality?

Comment: I really don't understand why 3 people clicked on "Looks OK".

- external link to google store
- the formatting is awful
- vague as hell. Plus if there were to be a default, it would be "Delete" :) most posts get here for a reason.

Comment: Almost a year ago I saw this link in a Meta question. Bookmarked it immediately. I wish it can be added to the help section, but hey, at least I'll pass it along! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Technical knowledge is irrelevant when > 90% of the items in the review queues are obvious trash that deserve nullification. For the remainder that may have some merit, you're expected to Skip if you don't have the necessary experience with the technology in question.

Comment: @IanKemp you got a point, but in triage, it's more 50/50 than 90/10. Also you can SOMETIMES learn enough in an hour of search about the technologies mentioned in the question, so you get to judge it properly. Which is even more time consuming... not recommended