# Create a community- (or moderator-) curated review training simulator

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Similar to [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289871/practice-queues-for-review-training), but not filled with random audits (which are sometimes [notoriously bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)) and more focused on training people on how to spot what reviews are looking for. We have a process like this for people asking questions, it makes a lot more sense to do this for reviews.

What the queue should have is

1. Clear *guidance* throughout the process. No simple notes next to buttons, but a solid step-by-step process as to what to look for.
2. No bans, but a place to learn how the process works in a ban-free environment.
3. Curated situations. Since we're making these good or bad, we can tell people exactly where they went wrong. And if we mess up, we can fix it. This could be done by CM or moderators (ideally community members with [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privs could submit potential simulations and have Mods or CMs approve).
4. Remedial work. Instead of a ban, give moderators the option to force people to "start over" in the simulator, or have a moderator force someone to go through a specific training that covers their situation. Potentially replaces the "Stop, Look and Listen" notice on failed audits as well.

Answer (score 21):

Point #4 is key. While bans and suspensions are a great way to let a user [*cool off*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), they're *not* a great way to guarantee the facilitation of a *learning process*. A recent example of this is the report of one user being review-banned for [1024 days](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48812977), because they had previously been review-banned for 512 days then [messed up again almost immediately](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48812996).

Having a mandatory, guided process will at least guarantee users have had the opportunity to learn. And having *positive* action (making the user do more work to continue) rather than *negative* action (keeping the user from doing work before continuing) will result in fewer disgruntled users and a better reviewing experience overall.

Comment: On the flip side, if someone is banned from reviewing for *1.5 years* and then immediately makes a bad review again after their return, I think a 3+ year ban *is* on point, because they clearly aren't the kind of discerning user we want reviewing others' contributions. If you get banned, it's because someone with the authority to decide so thought you did something wrong. It is reasonable to say the onus should be on *you* to ensure you do the legwork that so many others are clearly capable of doing without needing a ban to learn how to review correctly.

Comment: How would be the ban on point @TylerH if they didn't learn anything and the system made no effort in teaching them?

Comment: @Braiam The point of the ban is to prevent people who refuse to learn how to review from reviewing. That's what "on point" means.

Comment: Yes, however, they can't... "learn" from one failure, certainly when the system is so pre-disposed to selecting poor audits. though, i think it's fair to generally come to the conclusion that someone who has reached such a long suspension could potentially find a different way to contribute that works better for them.

Answer (score 15):

I would also suggest that individual examples have customized write-ups on *how* rules apply or do not apply to them. For example,

> **Not Spam**
>
> While this post certainly seems to be promoting a tool, a review of the poster's account reveals that they have contributed over a dozen well-received posts that do not promote any tool. Very few spammers contribute any non-promotional content. In addition, none of the red flags for spam found on [this] post are present.

In other words, we are moving from "You shouldn't have done X, you should have done Y instead." to "Here is why X is not applicable and why Y is much more appropriate.".

Comment: Another one i see complained about is people flagging garbage or gibberish as Spam when Spam has a very specific definition

Comment: @psubsee2003 While I agree that's not spam, [we are told to rude/abusive flag those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/244695). Since both red flags do the same thing anyways, it's not that big a deal

Comment: @Machavity right. In my example, I was more concerned about telling the user that things like NAA or non-flaggable low quality answers are not spam. Such content *is* referred to as spam on many other websites.

Comment: @Machavity I meant more that would not quite get to the level of a red flag (stuff that should qualify as "NAA" like you mentioned).  On my initial read of Robert's answer, I didn't see anything would specifically address those cases.  Upon rereading it, I can see it now, but maybe it could make it more explicit?