# Improvements to Example / Test Posts

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I've just got access to the review queues, there are the occasional test questions - which is great. However, it would be a nice addition if showed the way it should be answered / improved - so that it's a better on-boarding process.  I want to be better at it, and I've gotten some nice points from tidying up code, but having good solid lessons that showed a good process and improvements - would be great.

Comment: Something like [Create a community curated review training simulator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394534)? If you haven't read them already, these 3 may help you: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505), [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/), and [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650). Also, read all the pages in the help center :)

Comment: Thanks @Scratte - this is exactly what I'm looking for - would be good to have this more prominent when you first start out reviewing, such as an additional link on the top menu.

Comment: @Scratte Pro-tip: To shorten SO links, the "/question/" portion can be shortened to "/q/", and the part after that (the title of the post) can be removed altogether. This is often useful to fit more links into a comment. So, for example, the link to this post would just be: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397325. I've already manually merged your two comments above into one.