# Training mode for new reviewer

Tags: discussion, review-queues

After seven years, I have recently passed the magic 3K rep level and have tentatively tried a few Close and Reopen reviews in addition to the queues I think I know quite well. It has always struck me as odd that on achieving a privilege I am instantly deemed competent to act. It would seem much better to be put into a training mode initially until I have proved myself competent and then be allowed to do live reviews. Similarly, instead of just giving out review bans, the system could put you back into training mode until you proved yourself competent again.

I find the sneaky test reviews very negative - especially the patronising tone that it was checking I was paying attention.

Comment: Such a feature would take away from other much more important development. Your experience on the site should have exposed you to enough "things" to make reviewing decisions without an further training. As is always mentioned when it comes to any type of reviewing, the skip button is your friend.

Comment: Not exactly about the close vote queue but there is a few paragraphs on [unsalvagable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/578411) in the Triage guidance.

Comment: @Dave I don't get your point. Is not reviewing also better, when one doesn't feel educated enough?

Comment: Not sure I follow your statement/question @Scratte. Reviewing gets better with experience and there is really no substitute for that. You have to jump in and get your feet wet.

Comment: @Dave I don't like jumping in. I like being prepared. So where does it leave Stack Overflow, when I do not feel prepared enough to participate? There's even review bans to ensure users don't just jump in uneducated.

Comment: I think @Scratte has put it better than I did. I don't want to get to a point where I pick up a ban because I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @Dave simplest implementation of training mode looks rather low effort to me: system could just run review queue for the trainee user as usual with the only difference that all their decisions would go to `/dev/null` (except for maybe [meta-tag:review-audits]). Though most important part of this mode could be achieved even easier (requested long time ago): [Additional requirement for Steward or Reviewer badge to help new reviewers learn about using “Skip”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773)

Comment: This is a great idea, and it needs to happen. I like [Machavity's recent proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394534/),  And I would swear there was a good one on MSE, too, but I can't find it right this minute and don't have time to exhaustively search. We *especially* need the curated audits; that's something I've been arguing for for a long time. Audits are meant to be obvious, and the slap-on-the-wrist feeling would be fine, even good, in my opinion, were that always the case. But they're not always obvious, and that's because they're chosen by machine, not by moderators.

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to the Close Vote Queue! We have been waiting for you. We made sure not all questions are reviewed yet.

While I can imagine you feel insecure once you unlocked and exercised a privilege you just gained but I don't agree this would need training and/or extra care. The close vote privilege is basically an extension of a privilege you earned 2,500 rep ago. That is where we trusted you to flag posts. That also came with the Close option (and if you reviewed Triage you hopefully clicked unsalvageable more then once) except now your vote is counted as a proper vote where as earlier your flag only signaled for the 3K-ers that a post might need closing.

As for the audits. They are meant to be a bit "invasive", rude if you want, with the purpose to not take the given responsibility lightheartedly. That needs language that conveys that idea / feeling. Looks like that is achieved ;)

If you haven't seen much mishaps with your flags earlier I wouldn't worry too much nor consider yourself a trainee. Just use your common sense and skip a lot. If you need an extra pair of eyes to make a judgement call do know that both Meta and Chat, for example [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570),   have guidance ready and/or the folks around to help and assist you in your reviewing endeavor.