# Somewhat Tricky Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

EDIT: My post below shows a misunderstanding of what is expected in the review process, but I will leave it up for instructional purposes.

I recently failed the following audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7655083

I've failed one a few weeks ago, so I am now banned for 7 days.

I understand the point of the audits, but this one seemed a bit unfair. After all, I saw a question with some code and some SQL statement, and the answer mentioned Intellisense as the reason it is probably not compiling.

Now that is a very strange answer, and it turned out to be a really good one, but that is going to trip lots of people up, like me. I thought it was a garbage answer because it just seemed strange, and I could tell it was an audit because the user icon showed up as default with no name. Putting this together I downvoted it, and immediate saw that I was wrong. Strangely yes, intellisense can cause compilation failures apparently.

I'm not asking for an unban or anything, but could the audit posts be chosen a bit more carefully? I'm certainly not going to be able to catch nuances like that when I am glancing over 10 posts in a row and giving each one maybe 10-20 seconds. Or is that the point (i.e. to promote longer, more carefully thought through reviews)?

After all, the reviews are for new or late posts, not for established posts like that one written by masters like Jon Skeet.

Comment: You might want to take a look [at this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266105/failed-audit-review-but-the-counter-went-up/266108#266108).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I agree with the review and this answer's position as an audit. It appears, on the face of it, to be unrelated to the question - but if you read it thoroughly, you will see it actually is quite a comprehensive answer.

> Or is that the point (i.e. to promote longer, more carefully thought through reviews)?

Indeed. SO has always favoured quality over quantity, hence the limit on the number of votes that can be cast daily.

Comment: Point taken. I appear to have misjudged the time necessary for reviews, so I will stick to the topics I am most familiar with. This is now a bit of embarrassing post actually when I look at things in that light, but I'll leave it up because it's instructional.

Comment: @ChrisChambers a first post review can *easily* take a minute or two at the minimum to properly read the question and the answer. Then, if the post needs help (as many first posts do), another bit of time as the post is edited, duplicates checked, other things.  You might wish to check [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/289086) which is a very comprehensive overview of things to look at. Remember that a post only goes through FP queue once - your review of it is as binding as a mod's.