# Unable to comment on review audits

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, review-audits

I was trying to leave a comment on a review-audit (before I knew it was an audit) and when I clicked on the "add comment" button I received no indication that my "click" registered (I tried opening the review in another tab with the same result). If it makes a difference this was the late-answers queue.

I do know that there has been [some discussion recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) about failing review edits just by commenting, and that perhaps comments [shouldn't actually be posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237018/) on review-audits but I haven't seen anywhere that something was done about this.

So is this a bug, by design, not-reproducible?

If this is intentional then it seems like this would be one way to *game* the review-audits by trying to comment and if you are unable then that would mean it is an audit.

**Edit**

This is not a dupe of the question I linked to above, as the question was whether adding a comment should cause you to fail an audit. I'm talking about no longer being able to comment at all and whether this is intentional or not. Further in my case adding a comment would have actually been a *passing* action for the audit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Review audit failed after just clicking "add comment"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Did you read my question? This is **definitely not** a dupe of that question (which I linked to). That question is asking about failing, I'm asking about being unable to comment. If indeed this is an actual change that other question wouldn't even have come up since you can fail by commenting if you can't comment.

Comment: I read it, yes. IMHO an answer if this should be considered as a bug, should appear at the discussion you mentioned. As soon you're choosing to comment on an audit question that expected a specific behavior from your side, you'll fail the audit.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually in this particular case it was a *bad answer* so commenting would have passed the audit. I found out it was an audit when I clicked to flag the answer, I had just intended to leave a comment first.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @gnat I'm assuming you are saying I should edit to indicate why this isn't a dupe, rather than saying that you believe it to be a dupe too.

Comment: @Jack yes. I saw that you referred that other question from the very beginning, but as far as I can tell, this turned out insufficient to convince readers that it's different

Comment: @gnat I think it is most likely the *pile* on affect in that one person votes to close and every one else just glances at the linked question without actually reading it and votes along.

Comment: maybe. [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) is a known issue

Comment: True, I wonder if some review-audits could be especially designed to catch that (I haven't looked to see if that was already suggested,but I wouldn't be surprised if it was).

Comment: Perhaps related to [Don't let users comment on review audit questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237018/).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Related in that both are dealing with comments, and perhaps as a result of that some change was made. However the problem over there wasn't that the user was allowed to post the comment but that it *was* actually posted. I wasn't able to comment at all. I will add that link though to my question.

Comment: I have experienced this behavior also (both in 'positive post' and 'negative post' audits). To me it looks like a bug!

Comment: Just saw the same behavior while commenting in the reopen queue.