# Commenting on an audit gave it away

Tags: discussion, review-audits, review-abuse

I got this question as an audit today: [How to identify the color of image in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588958/how-to-identify-the-color-of-image-in-c)

It read:

> I want to identify the total color present in image in c# and i want to change the individual color in the image ?

I could see that the question was low quality. But I wanted to give the OP a second chance to improve the question. So I tried to comment:

> Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "total color present in image". Do you want to get a list of all colors *used* in the image? Also, your post contains ***two*** questions.

When I submitted the comment, I was told that the *comment cannot be submitted because the question frozen, on-hold, or closed* (or something similar to that). So that's how I did not fail the audit, that I might have failed.

So here's my concern: ***Commenting on a post when reviewing can be used by rep-mongers to sniff the audits***.

So I propose that reviewers should be able to comment on review audits. It does not matter if comment goes to `/dev/null`. Just use AJAX to show it as submitted.

Also, this seems to be a bug that was introduce by the fix to this bug: [Unable to comment on review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267261/unable-to-comment-on-review-audits)

Comment: I may be an optimist, but I don't really believe that robo-reviewers are generally malicious, just incompetent. I doubt many would actively try to circumvent the system.

Comment: It seems SE fulfilled [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237018/).

Comment: I don't want to type out a well though through comment to try and guide the user just to find out I was speaking to a review-audit instead. The system should be focused on user experience first

Comment: well, at least it's not ending the audit when you click `add comment` anymore