# Getting failed for review audits when they are blatantly wrong

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5949097

This is now the second time this has happened to me, where I'm "failed" on an audit which I believe is wrong. I get the distinct impression that these audit questions are automated which is a completely naive approach.

At best it can be argued it's not as verbose an answer as one might like but I certainly did not see reason to flag it for deletion.

The last one I was failed on was even worse because it says click here to see the audit you failed, and the answer is missing completely (presumably deleted). It was for a message which, based on the comment below, was mistakenly marked (and accepted) as spam, then the audit then assumed that if I did not give a 'spam' answer as well that I was wrong and needed to sit in the corner for a while.

Assuming this really is an automated process, can we:

1. ditch the automated selection of audit questions completely, or
2. have an avenue to mark an audit question as incorrect or at least heavily disputable and thus not suitable for a black-or-white audit

and just in case others (likely) don't see what I see for that URL:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I 'm often frightened how many anwser, from a plurality of users, are marked and or delete as "NAN" or "VLQ".
That these are taken as a reference for an audit is more than annoying. 
In a close - audit in which a bad question used as a reference, you can at least make the question even down vote them unfit for an audit.

Comment: You clicked "No Action Needed" on a *five word answer with no formatting*. I think this audit worked as intended.

Comment: @AirThomas Code-only answers are blocked, so just about any edit is putting words into that user's mouth.  I'd've downvoted though, since as I recall, that doesn't answer the question correctly.  But it's still _an_ answer, just a bad one.

Comment: @Izkata IIRC a downvote would have passed this audit. Can't seem to find a "bad post" audit to test it on at the moment, but in theory, the only ways to fail should be by taking no action or upvoting.

Comment: @AirThomas It's been said repeatedly here on Meta that bad or even completely incorrect answers should be downvoted, *not* flagged, and *not* deleted, and the answer had already been downvoted enough IMO. I probably would've picked "No Action Needed" too.

Comment: @hvd If you judge that a post in the queue is bad, and the action you take as a reviewer doesn't reflect that judgment, expect to fail audits. If this burns someone who leaves a critical *comment* (and clicks "I'm Done") in lieu of downvoting or flagging, I'd consider that a significant flaw. But I would suggest that when you decide to *withhold judgment* as a reviewer, you are not acting as a reviewer, and the appropriate action to take is "Skip."

Comment: @AirThomas There's a difference between "bad according to my personal opinion", and "bad according to SO policies". I attempt to judge posts based on what's acceptable on SO, not based on what I think should be acceptable on SO.

Comment: @AirThomas: The answer attempted to answer the question.  Answers do not need to talk in circles for a paragraph or two when five words suffice.

Comment: @AirThomas: where a simple answer will suffice, I would often prefer that to the endless waffling and paddling some answers give to try and look more informative or knowledgeable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that this appears to be a legitimate attempt at an answer and doesn't need to flagged or deleted by the community. That said, flagging and deletion are not the be-all and end-all of reviewing. It only takes seven characters to make this answer a complete sentence with proper formatting:

```
Use `service openvpn status` (as root).
```

It's still not a *great* answer, but that's an improvement by any reasonable metric. It takes minimal effort, it requires no domain knowledge, and you have full edit privileges so you don't need to worry that you're taking up other reviewers' time to polish what could be a technically wrong answer. [The guidance here is explicit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/254929):

> If you don't care about a post, just click *Skip* or *Not sure*.

> Answers in the Late Answers review queue are also First Posts or very
>   nearly so, since they are posted by [new users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), so apply all the
>   steps for [reviewing First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180030#180030) here.

> Don't focus on the actual answer itself. Focus on the formatting and
>   the etiquette of the author.

I'm not accusing you of being a bad reviewer or saying I would necessarily expect any good reviewer to pass this audit.<sup>1</sup> That said, let's have some perspective here: You chose not to improve an answer that had plenty of room for improvement. The consequences you suffered were:

- You didn't receive a tick mark toward your next badge.
- Your ego was bruised.

What you did wasn't terrible, but it also wasn't the best option available. You're under no obligation to edit but if you notice an opportunity to edit and don't feel like taking it, you should pass the responsibility to another reviewer by choosing **Skip**. You could have left a helpful comment for the author about formatting and complete sentences.<sup>2</sup> You could have downvoted it based purely on the way it was presented. Instead you acted to dequeue the post while sending a signal that you didn't see any way to improve it.<sup>3</sup>

In response, you were [given a nudge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/254929) that prompted you to critically evaluate your process, which is what I meant by my comment that this audit worked as intended. A little introspection goes a long way, and even if it hasn't convinced you that you did anything wrong, at least it'll keep you on your toes and [help you to pass future audits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhyqP.png).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm not even 100% sure that editing this answer would have passed the audit, though [this recent thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224312/254929) says it would. The audit system is far from perfect as evidenced by all the [quirky behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228932/late-answers-audits-should-show-comments#comment750948_228932) that comes up on meta.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> [You might still fail the audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260803/2359271), but at least then you'd have the comfort of being [cited by staff as an example of someone who had been wrongly botslapped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234153/254929).</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> You could argue that "needed" is semantically ambiguous. Still, [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/254929) is not ambiguous when it says, "Most posts can be improved. Use the Edit option, and edit thoroughly."</sub>

Comment: No, my 'ego' was not bruised. It's not something I take personally as it is obviously automated. I simply question the wisdom of such automation and whether it's worth wasting my time on working with a system which is broken enough to suspend me so spuriously.

Comment: and I have been 'failed' in the past for editing an answer that supposedly should have been rejected, so I don't bother doing that any more.

Answer (score 4):

Audits are automatically selected, based on the votes a post gets. If a post gets a lot of upvotes and no downvotes/flags/close-votes, it is a candidate for a "known good" audit. Similarly downvotes and/or flags make it a candidate for a "known bad" audit.

The reason for this is that we need a lot of audits; manual selection of audits simply doesn't scale to the size of Stack Overflow.

But it's clear that the system of automated selection is not perfect; bad posts can get a lot of upvotes, and good posts can get a lot of downvotes.

If you are certain that a post should not be used as an audit, you can vote or flag as is necessary. For a bad post that is used as a "known good" audit, flag or downvote as is appropriate. Conversely, upvote a good post that is incorrectly used as a "known bad". This should prevent the post from being used as an audit in the future.

Also, you can raise the issue on Meta as you have done; note that the tag wiki excerpt for [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) explicitly mentions that it is to be used for discussing issues with specific audits.

On meta.stackexchange.com, there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/168333) to bring a human factor into the audit system, which seems to address your concerns.

Comment: although I am a huge fan of bringing-human-factor, worth noting that bugs like one raised here can be fixed without it. Root cause is that audits like this one are picked from posts deleted by 2K users in LQ queue, which is unreliable by definition (30,000 reviewers with 2K rep there can do whatever they want, as long as answer isn't accepted and not positive score). Even automatically, "known bad" audits should be picked from those deleted by moderators / trusted users, iirc there was a feature request at MSO or MSE about this

Comment: Yes, you can bring up bad audits on Meta, and get agreement that they are bad audits. But you still get banned for failing them. So in the end, it doesn't really help much.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Moderators will occasionally lift bans for terrible audits.