# Shouldn't this first answer audit test have a few comments?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8029672) flags as being a test for reviewers. While I agree that the answer is good and has (at first glance) nicely written code, it also has *zero comments* in the code and only a single line of explanatory text, despite introducing things like `Parallel.for`.

I was caught for adding a comment that read: "This looks like good code, but it would be stellar with a few comments."

In general, what's the remedy when it seems like a post could be 'just a little bit better'?

Comment: I personally don't think that a comment should fail a "good" audit, but thats just me.

Comment: Note that comments are not displayed in FP and LA audits until the audit is revealed. They *are* displayed in every other audit type I'm aware of, and they *are* (of course) displayed normally in FP and LA.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment (which is a feature request asking for this to be changed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a post pings your audit-dar, open it in a new tab to see what the deal is. (It can't hurt to do that *all the time* until you get a better feel for it.)

Normally, yes, comment on posts that could use improvement, even if they're already quite good. The audit system is just ... limited, and has some known rough spots.

Comment: Since we're talking about first posts, I'm not sure if the audit in question *would* ping my audit-dar. Anyway, it's good advice.