# Failed audit when commenting on code-only answer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed the review audit for the accepted code-only answer to the question ["
How to get excluded collection without a second LINQ query?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141523/how-to-get-excluded-collection-without-a-second-linq-query).

It was suppose to be a high quality answer, and I should have left it or upvoted it. Instead I took the time to write a comment saying that code-only answeres should be avoided if possible, and that some explanation would be helpful both to the OP and future visitors.

Did I do the wrong thing? Or was the audit flawed?

**EDIT:** This has been marked as a duplicate. From the top voted answer of the [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) (or rather it's duplicate):

> This most definitely should be changed. It is fundamentally illogical (which as a programmer, is something I tend to despise) and presumptive of the reviewer's actions in so many ways that it is impossible to believe an algorithm could handle, or even begin to handle, without a team of psychologists, all of the predictive text experts from Google, and a psychic.

So in the light of that, let me rephrase: This audit is flawed and should be removed. Could someone fix that?

Comment: This is the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9330465) in the first posts queue.

Comment: Comments may considered the wrong action. If you're not sure, rather skip.

Comment: Why would it be wrong to comment on a code-only answer just encouraging the user to add some explanation? Not flagging, not saying it is wrong or bad, just saying that some comments would be nice?

Comment: @CRABOLO Well, that one leads to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) one where the top answer say that the audit was flawed.

Comment: @CRABOLO While the link was helpful, I do not think it qualify as a duplicate as questions tagged with disputed audits are about the indivdual audit.

Answer (score 4):

That is a little bit unfortunate but I might have failed this audit as well.

For the casual observer it might not be immediately clear what kind of magic is happening there. A link to one of the used LINQ methods would make the answer better, although it is not wrong in its current form.

This answer was chosen as an audit because it had no down votes and 11 up votes.

I'm not sure if the audit should be removed because it does require reviewers to pay attention. The answer is OK-ish but not great by my standards.

I'm in favor of saying sorry to you but keep the audit in place. If more reviewers trip over the audit we might need to reconsider that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the future, should I keep commenting on code-only answers I find both in review queues and elsewhere? When it is from fairly new users I often do that, since they might not know that more than just code is encouraged in answers.

Comment: I would keep commenting but not from the First Post review queue, in case of code-only answers choose Skip.

Comment: Isn't it odd that you have to hide a valid action from the audit system? Sort of like saying "yeah, this is the correct way to do it, but just don't do it on the test"?

Comment: Yeah, that is maybe weird. But the audit system isn't perfect and so are our regular users that should maybe down-vote code-only answers. I'm on the side that I don't like seeing users that are trying to help-out by moderating get review-banned because the automatic selection of audits doesn't compensate for cases where nobody cared to down vote. So to keep you going and not get you banned makes me hand out this weird advice.

Comment: Ok, I get things are not perfect, just got a bit confused. Thanks for sorting that out for me, I appreciate it. Now back to reviewing... :-)