# Failed audit on code-only answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Multiple questions on meta indicate, that code-only answers, if they are self-explanatory and, what's more important, correct, do not fall into *low quality*: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303772/failed-audit-when-commenting-on-code-only-answer), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258676/7606764).

Meanwhile I failed the audit when I accepted a code-only answer:

[image]

What is wrong with that?

Edit: I think this question is more specific, than duplicate candidate as it limits itself to code-only answers.

Comment: Hard to say without any context. If it answers the question, it should be accepted. If it is just a chunk of random code not related to/answering the question, it should be deleted.

Comment: Meh. I usually skip on code-only answers found on review. You can never tell how other users would have voted on those. Remember that audits are chosen automatically because of the reception a post gets.

Comment: So audits are pretty much a lottery, right? This answer has one downvote, so you can't tell...

Comment: They are OK to check that you are more or less paying attention. I do not think they are intended to do much more than that.

Comment: Yeah, and as the result I can't review for 2 weeks^^

Comment: That's not because of this *one* audit, though.

Comment: Right, but last time it was similar. I just didn't react as I wasn't banned. Today same thing but with consequences...

Comment: @Andronicus You said that no action was required on a low quality post from a queue that exists to help you improve the quality of such posts.  The audit was doing its job.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality)

Answer (score 12):

> *"if they are self-explanatory"*.

That answer is not self-explanatory.

It's a code dump where the OP has to figure out what changed, and more importantly: *why*. It doesn't explain why the changes make the code work.

Answers like that *are* of low quality. Maybe not enough to flag or delete them, but they definitely don't look "Ok". (I usually downvote cases like that)

When in doubt, <kbd>Skip</kbd> the review.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190456/discussion-on-answer-by-cerbrus-failed-audit-on-code-only-answer). If you have a counter-point, make it in your own answer, where you can properly present and defend it.

Answer (score 8):

The failure here seems to be due to two misconceptions:

1. That your only options on the first post queue are, No action
   needed, Edit, Flag and Skip.

   In actuality, there are several other options including upvote, downvote, and commenting. These options are conspicuously present in this queue as opposed to others like triage.
2. That the first post queue is just for checking for correctness, like triage or low quality queue.

   Like Servy pointed out in the comments, action is expected as part of this queue even if the answer is not bad enough to flag. The bar is higher than triage. The whole point of it is to help others improve the quality of their posts.

In summary, I think the correct actions would have been:

- Edit: If you know about the technology, you could edit the answer yourself to provide context.
- Comment: If you don't know about the technology, you can comment and ask OP to provide context
- Downvote: You can downvote if you're inclined.
- Skip: You can skip if you're not inclined, or not sure.