# Is it consensus that commenting should (not) lead to failing review audits?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits

I was about to add a comment to an answer when it hit me. It says my “review” was inappropriate, though I was just about to add a comment.

The *First Posts* review form encourages to “comment to leave constructive feedback (or [criticism](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)) for the author”. It’s not like flagging a high-quality post as VLQ. Even the most revered answer might bear a comment, be it for adding comment-eligible information to an otherwise complete post.

My follow-up question why this was so has been put into question multiple times, like this one: [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) It seems this did flare tempers before, and from the discussions, I think I feel a tendency towards comments not being judged as inappropriate actions.

**Is that so, or will this audit-fail feature remain as-is?**

In the latter case, is it logical that I am not supposed to comment on well-accepted answers at all?

Comment: I agree, especially since you may want to do many actions to a post, you shouldn't be penalized for wanting to comment first.

Comment: I have found the audit-fail feature to be dubious at times also. I have failed a couple times for flagging a question as "asks multiple questions" when it *clearly asks multiple questions* but apparently the post was supposed to be fine... dunno. Slightly frustrating...

Comment: @JeffC: In this case, raise the issue on Meta; audits are selected automatically (based on votes), so some "bad" posts end up as "good" audits accidentally. If you raise the issue here, a moderator can remove this bad audit.

Comment: @Matthieu is that what we should do? I had the same issue with a comment auto-failing an audit and was going to raise the question on meta but saw the duplicate posts, so I decided not to.

Comment: @Trobbins: comment auto-failing is different: it's a "bad audit system" issue, not a "bad audit" issue. We need one report per "bad audit system" issue and one per "bad audit" issue, the former to improve the system, the latter to cull the audits.

Comment: @Matthieu Makes sense, I wasn't implying we bog down Meta SO with all failed audits due to commenting.

Comment: @MatthieuM It's not even that it's a bad audit, it's a bad system. It got me once as well. I recognised it was a good question and was going to let it pass the review. However I wanted to leave a constructive comment, not realising that leaving a comment will always count as making a question fail the review.

Comment: @ABoschman: This is exactly what I said...

Comment: @MatthieuM. So you did, my bad. Failed to see you were responding to JeffC's comment, rather than to the question.

Comment: I agree - also the reason for failing an audit last week.

Comment: Wasn't this one of of "test" questions? If so there is only a right and wrong answer. Overuse of comments is not needed on the site and you should have chosen a different route. I'm sure that's the way the devs see it

Comment: @Jesse: It’s not that binary at all. It might be that way when a quality post gets reviewed VLQ. In contrast, adding a single comment is neither “overuse” nor *a priori* redundant or obsolete. The system can’t know, so it should either hide this function during review or allow comments (without audit fails).

Comment: I disagree. When I am doing the audits my goal is to move through them quickly and efficiently. I haven't failed a test question before out of maybe 100 I've done. I used to work ticket systems so for me extra comments on a valid response is just garbage cluttering the page. To add to that the review system likely doesn't want you commenting on old posts used as a test

Comment: @Jesse: My review/fail ratio is better that that, and I don’t want to get *quickly* through reviews but thoroughly, and I still feel there’s an improvement possible.

Comment: Nah man. It's real simple. Should you comment on a post that is 3 years old. Nah. What I do if I want to comment is open it in a new tab and viola I see 18 comments and I think. No need and move on. Haven't failed one test yet

Answer (score 34):

**Yes, there is [clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262511/1340389) [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260810/1340389) that commenting should *not* lead to audit failures.**

However, it is not clear to me that the Stack Exchange team is interested in directly implementing this change at this time.  I charitably suppose they plan on completely revamping the queue at some point in the future, but haven't finished yet, and therefore are not interested in half-measures.  I am [not entirely convinced](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/7?topic=perfection) of the wisdom of this strategy, but then I don't properly know that this is necessarily the strategy they are actually employing.

(Incidentally, I don't even *do* reviews much anymore, given how often we get these "audits are kind of broken" meta posts.  It just sounds like more trouble than it's worth.)

Comment: Do you know if they're going to actually implement this at some point?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: I flagged this answer, requesting comment from Shog9 or someone else with the ability to speak authoritatively on that topic.  The flag was summarily declined.  I interpret that as "No, we're not going to do this, and we consider it too unimportant to even bother with an official announcement of that fact."

Comment: I do wish that SO staff would be more responsive to Meta requests like this, especially if there seems to be community consensus surrounding it. (Or, at least, some acknowledgment that they reviewed it).

Comment: You could review suggested edits or help and improvement. Suggested audits are always obvious because they've been made by a bot which has no way of being able to suggest useful edits, and help and improvement doesn't have any audits at all because you can't robo-review help and improvement (the only options are to edit or to skip).

Comment: in the low quality queue you get "cannot comment on audit". This doesn't fail the audit, this even helps you with it :)

Comment: sort of update, they are currently (finally) planning improvements to review queues and looking for feedback. Suggestion that commenting should _pass_ audits instead of failing [is submitted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354290/165773): "Attempt to comment demonstrates that you pay attention while reviewing. Congratulations, you passed this audit."

Answer (score -29):

By completing review tasks you have essentially volunteered yourself as a semi-sentient reading monkey for the benefit of StackOverflow. It's very nice that you should have chosen to do so, but it doesn't qualify you for "worker's rights", to be treated fairly or with respect, or indeed for anything apart from some brightly colored pixels.

You are a cog in the machine, a small piece of the workflow which can't be replaced by code (yet). The audit do not exist for your benefit, they are there to make sure you are still working efficiently. StackOverflow doesn't want free, useful labor done in a way which is surprising, or difficult to quantify, or doesn't exactly reflect the way they want things to work.

Don't like it? Try doing something else! Perhaps you could use your time in some genuinely creative way, or maybe just one which is more entertaining for you personally. It might even be an option to enjoy unmediated interaction with another live human being!

Comment: I’m aware that SO grades Q&A quality over user feelings. That’s okay, most of the time. But as my assumption seems to be well-founded, there still might be a systemic cog that should be oiled, replaced or even removed; in our case, this is the “fail audit on comment” gearwheel.

Comment: the way the 'machine' works can be changed, reviewers do get some limited benefit from reviewing in terms of partipcation badges, and I wonder if high reputation users gain much of the reputation via edits from the **Needs Editing** review queue, eg reputation of 20,000 would mean upvotes of 100 on 200 different questions (many reviewers haven't answered that many questions), or editing 2,000 posts. Reputation isn't explained well in the help documentation for new users it seems.

Comment: It also seems somewhat strange to me that flagging a very high number of questions earns you silver and gold participation badges. While it's great to have people wanting to flag spam and flag questions for moving to another stackexchange site it does encourage the flagging to close of questions that are 'unclear' or answers that are 'low quality' - especially for new posters who get their own review queue. New users often appear in the Late Answers review queue meaning fast downvotes or flags happen before the person asking has seen the answer.

Comment: @Mousey - If all a brand new user did was edit posts, they'd stop getting rep for it at 2k.  [proof](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). [A quick query at SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/369567/476391/average-number-of-posts-by-20k-users) suggests that users with >20k rep have 1225 posts on average. (As a guesstimate, that's slightly more than 1.5 upvotes each if all are answers.)

Comment: you can answer less than 40 questions, ask only 10 and get a 50K reputation. My point was that reviews skew reputation to a degree that the meaning is lost.