# How to deal with falsely failed audits?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The current audit system for the First Post queue audits currently considers commenting on a post as a negative action. I recently came across [this audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18072564), where I intended to leave a comment and asking the poster for clarification (firewall settings, etc.), which is what the comment system is designed to do.

I've come across several audits now where I left a comment relevant to the question and ended up failing the audit, for whatever reason.

The [consensus of the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307082/501011) seems to be that commenting should not lead to failed reviews. Even more interesting is [the comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits#comment490383_307082), claiming that the StackExchange team does not seem interested in fixing the apparent issue for reasons unknown to the community.

---

How am I supposed to react to failed audits now? I understand that the reason for audits is to thwart botting and cause users to pay more attention when they review questions. However, when audits are failed because *I attempted to help improve the question*, then I feel like the whole audit system is entirely absurd.

Should I just keep going along and hope I am not getting any more audit questions? Or should I just consider the First Post queue broken as of now and stick to Triage?

Comment: Think you meant a different link for the audit question - you've put the meta one there twice :)

Comment: @JonClements I edited the link now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: One could argue that a question asked 29 days ago, a score of 21 with ~4.5k views and 4 answers probably isn't quite the same as all the others that say *This is the first question asked by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post*... and should just scream "this is made up - it's not really a first post!"... (bearing in mind that items in the first posts queue have only just been posted) - So anything that isn't posted today and/or doesn't have a score that's around zero should be considered iffy...

Comment: @JonClements Doesn't that defeat the purpose of an audit? I mean, I don't specifically look out for potential audit questions and instead just try to be helpful for what I assume to be first post. And given the body of the question (just an error message), it might very well have been a first post by a user just now.

Comment: The purpose of the audit is to check you're paying attention to what you're presented. If you're presented something that can't even be a valid First Post (and it's easy to see when it's faked) - you should ideally notice...

Comment: I haven't considered it from that perspective, because that seems unnecessarily hostile towards the user. It's as if the system is set up to make you fail, rather than help you improve your auditing (which in turn helps others ask better questions).

Comment: At least it makes it obvious - if it'd have made that first post looks more like a first post and changed the views, score, and date, then I think it'd be a valid argument of "setting users up for failure" - but as it stands... it's not trying to be sneaky and the displayed info really does make it obvious.

Comment: @JonClements That makes the audit system really counter-intuitive at best, but as I mentioned in my question, that's nothing new

Comment: It's far from perfect but we're all hoping it's one of the the things the DAG team will be looking at and working on...