# Can an unintended consequence of "review audits" be fewer reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just spent 5 minutes wrestling with how to craft feedback to a new contributor without being harsh or demeaning, only to be played by a review audit. My feedback was deleted, and I was told that I passed.

I don't have the time, but feel that I need to give back to the community that has given me so much. Whenever I get tested, I immediately stop reviewing and go do other things.

I know reviews are needed, but am I the only one to feel this way?

[image]

Comment: Not really the point but I would have downvoted and moved on.

Comment: It seems like there's some valid feedback buried here—which is that it's not a positive experience to have your effort invalidated because it was an audit rather than a genuine review. As an example, if you try to edit an audit the review task is ended _before_ you spend time editing the post for almost this exact reason. There might be some room for improvement/something similar to be done for comments, but that'd be a somewhat different conversation that the one currently proposed.

Comment: It appears you spent your time to provide feedback on a comment submitted as an answer.

Comment: I think an intended consequence of the audit is fewer bad reviewers, but what happened here would have a consequence of fewer good reviewers.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Good reviewers learn to quickly identify contributions that are worth spending time improving, a comment submitted as an answer, isn’t worth the authors valuable time.

Comment: @SecurityHound I admit that I completely forgot about the flagging function, but on the right where the review actions are, the only available options are "looks ok', 'edit', or 'share feedback'. So I 'left a helpful comment for the new poster'

Comment: Years ago, I stopped reviewing because of review audits. Not only because it felt like a waste of time, but often the audits are considerably trickier than a majority of actual review items. So reviews are no longer a small contribution that you make to the community, but they become a test of your concentration and awareness of multiple aspects related to a post. Instead of getting something right with your contribution, you have to get everything right for it to count as a valid contribution.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes, obviously. Nobody should be surprised by this: review audits are there to catch out insincere/sloppy reviews. This will inevitably lead to fewer reviewers. And it is not a frictionless process, so it will also negatively affect some well-meaning reviewers, who will subsequently stop reviewing. This has been known for some time and it's generally deemed an acceptable loss to combat bad reviews. It's *inherently* a trade-off. — This doesn't invalidate OP's experience, which still sucks, and if this can be improved, by all means it should.

Comment: pro tip for reviewing is the save yourself some time is to save some long comments in a text file to quickly copy and paste

Comment: "Whenever I get tested, I immediately stop reviewing and go do other things." Why? I don't understand this. Getting a bit tested should not hurt that much. On other hand, I can understand being angry at spending time crafting responses for a non-existent review task just for checking. That's the annoying part of it. Maybe the checking can be done more clever.

Comment: @wruckieb = Here is a pro trip.  Open the question in another tab in your browser.  You can then make sure you always do the proper reviewer action.

Comment: It's good to keep in mind it may be better to help 5 people for 20 seconds, than to help 1 person for  minutes by crafting a personalized message. There are canned comment userscripts that can help, and at the size of Stack Overflow, there are always more to help. This is especially true if the OP seemed to invest very little effort in their post

Comment: "Whenever I get tested, I immediately stop reviewing and go do other things." - I kind of feel that. Whenever I try to find something to answer, as soon as I have waded through question 4 or 5 that needed to be closed as a duplicate I tend to just give up. It feels like trying to walk up an escalator that goes down. Even though 4 or 5 questions isn't all that much. It is kind of that added weight of selffulfilling prophecy I think, where you go "Oh not THIS again". Based on all previous experiences.

Comment: "Whenever I get tested, I immediately stop reviewing and go do other things." Me too. It feels like I'm playing a computer game rather than cleaning up the site. It's also insulting that I'm being tested after having proven my worth on the site, and in the queues, for so long. Once I'm audited, I just leave. Eventually I get over it. But it's pushed me further and further away each time.

Comment: A tip on spotting review audits (which would have worked in this case): If it's in one of the "Answers" queues and the line under the "Review the following answer" sub-heading starts with "0 answers", then it has been deleted and is a "known bad" audit.

Answer (score 14):

> Can an unintended consequence of "review audits" be fewer reviewers?

##### Well, no

If you count robo-reviewers as reviewers, then no. It's not unintentional because review audits are there to keep out robo-reviewers. Pretty simple. See also: [Is there any hard evidence that audits improve review quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316484/11107541) (TL;DR yes there is).

##### But also yes

That being said, you're not the first to be confused or frustrated with some part of the review audit system, having run into something that didn't feel good or wasn't very fair.

- [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412271/11107541)
- [How to deal with falsely failed audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359873/11107541)
- [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795/11107541)
- [First Answers Review Suspension because of plagiarized answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418792/11107541)
- [Where's the spam in this audit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408558/11107541)

Read a couple of those and you'll see other people express frustration with the audit system, and maybe even some who say they have stopped doing reviews because of those frustrations. So, yes. With respect to those people who (probably) weren't robo-reviewing, it is quite unintended that they have stopped doing reviews, and no- you are not the only one who feels this way.

##### Extra readings

Loosely related on the topic of confusing/bad audits:

- On MSE: [Add an "I don't understand" option for review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/997587)
- On MSE: [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/997587)
- On MSE answering to [Help us identify new roles for community members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/997587): [Audit Mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384179/997587)

Comment: While I agree the review system needs some work, alright a lot of work, it's all we got.  So one can either learn how the system works, learn to to identify audit(s) as they are not meant to catch reviewers, who are selecting the correct review action.

Comment: eh, that it's all we have, isn't an excuse not to bring it up often as a pain point/frustration that the community faces when dealing with these older systems that aren't really working well.

Comment: @SecurityHound most of the queues are emulatable using SEDE or just browsing custom filters or search bar queries. If you're suspended from review though, you can't approve suggested edits.

Comment: @SecurityHound, "So one can either learn how the system works, learn to to identify audit(s)", Yeah but then you're just playing a computer game aren't you? You're not actually helping to improve the site, and the audit isn't working as it should anyway in that case. * *sigh* *

Comment: @SecurityHound Or, I could not bother at all. Like nearly everyone here, I'm not payed to do this. And while I did want to help, failing an audit was just the site saying "we don't want *your* help." And after seeing how egregious the frequency of the audits was, I stopped. Mission accomplished, I suppose.

Comment: @ouflak - If I am reviewing actual contributions, instead of being tricked by marginal audits, then I am absolutely improving the site. In my experience only two types of individuals end up being suspended from reviews (other than bots), individuals not paying attention or individuals choosing the incorrect review option. My advice helps neither group, since both groups, will continue to (not pay attention) and (choose the wrong review option)

Comment: @ouflak yeah kind of it is a game. You have to play it if you want to help out. There is always a gap between what you shouldn't need to have to do and reality. In this case you shouldn't need to have to check if what you see in front of you is truth or a lie. But people do robo reviewing, so we're sunk. You have to stomach it by playing the game. What I think makes it easy for people to choose to give up reviewing (which should conflict with a desire to help out) is because there is so little proof that what you do matters. The site keeps chugging along.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, I've had the same thing happen, after being puzzled something egregious apparently went un-edited for so long (e.g. wrong tags and title typos, or a question that's almost answerable due to confusion about the subject matter), and I decide what to do with it, then discover it was just a stupid audit that wasted multiple minutes of my time.  Or with edit reviews, a potentially partly helpful edit where you have to understand the post to see if the edit really is correct.

So I modified my procedure: **before spending any time thinking about what to edit or comment, I middle-click the question title to open the actual question in a new tab.**  Usually I find it already closed or deleted, so it was just an audit.  Shake my head and move on, after selecting the appropriate leave open or whatever.

Having to keep in mind that the audit system might be about to waste your time with every review item you look at makes it even less enjoyable that it otherwise would be, but that will save you from the worse feeling of having invested some serious thought only to get tricked like [Charlie Brown trying to kick the football](https://peanuts.fandom.com/wiki/Football_gag).

---

Even so, I don't usually review via the queue, rather by looking at activity in the tags I follow, which are low enough traffic that I can look at everything that happens in them.  (That doesn't alert me to suggested edits until after they're approved, but most times when I have looked at edit reviews, the edit queue is empty when filtered for a few tags I want to review in, like [assembly] [cpu-architecture] [avx].)

Usually when I review, it's because I notice a pending edit on a question I was already looking at because it was recently active (e.g. posted).  Or a minor edit that didn't fix the problems, but the OP was wildly over-optimistic, so I'll go find it in the reopen queue and vote to leave closed.

I might do a few more reviews until I exhaust the tag-filtered subset of that queue.  I don't feel like my time is well-spent reviewing an edit on a subject I'm not an expert in, vs. manually looking at new questions and finding duplicates for them.  (Or old questions that I come across.)

The queue filter only allows 3 tags, and I'm not so keen to do reviews that I'd want to include more anyway.  When I have some not-so-low-traffic tags like [c][assembly][performance] in the filter, I tend to stop before cleaning out that part of the queue.