# I am appealing a temporary suspension from SO Review for "failing" two audits in which I attempted to edit posts marked as spam instead of deleting

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I've completed ~1000 tasks, and this is the first time I've ever been suspended from the review queues.

The suspension message reads:

> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> - /review/low-quality-posts/34424050
> - /review/low-quality-posts/34431089
>
> We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks.

That is blatantly wrong. It failed me on both audits because I attempted to *edit* the posts. Why would I try to edit posts if I wasn't actually reviewing them? In fact, I will show that I reviewed (at least one of) them *more thoroughly* than the original reviewers did.

- [review/low-quality-posts/34424050](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34424050)

[image: review/low-quality-posts/34424050]

The first post is a high quality answer with minor formatting issues I would've liked to fix. People who "aren't actually reviewing the tasks" might see the URL and jump to conclude that it's spam. Except it's clearly a string template, and **that same URL is contained in the question** and was only copied into the answer. Therefore, this user's answer was **definitely not spam** and was wrongly flagged and deleted in the first place!

[image: question to review/low-quality-posts/34424050]

---

- [review/low-quality-posts/34431089](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34431089)

[image: review/low-quality-posts/34431089]

The second audit does contain a hyperlink to an individual's website, but it otherwise gives exactly what the question asked for. Instead of recommending deletion, I determined it was best to simply remove the link and keep the answer. Is that not reasonable? After further scrutiny, I now suspect the answer is AI generated, but I cannot objectively justify that suspicion. In any case, I don't think it's fair to audit reviewers on the ability to identify content potentially from AIs or know exactly the protocol for handling it.

Furthermore, the question to this answer was closed for "seeking recommendations", but I believe this is *also* a mistake. As the title states, the question is "What is embedded AI?". It primarily asks for a definition, not a recommendation, and the request for an authoritative source is inconsequential, if not completely warranted.

[image: question for review/low-quality-posts/34431089]

For these reasons, my suspension and the failed audits should be retracted immediately.

As the suspension messages says:

> Poor reviews negatively affect the community. Please give each task
> adequate attention in the future

Poor audits also negatively affect the community's willingness to provide free content review. Please select posts used to audit reviewers more carefully.

Comment: "_Poor audits also negatively affect the community's willingness to provide free content review. Please select posts used to audit reviewers more carefully._" - related: [Can an unintended consequence of "review audits" be fewer reviewers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423166/11107541) (and my answer post there)

Comment: I don't see how the second answer could be provided to an on-topic question. There is no need to edit completely off-topic question or answers to those.

Comment: @Alexei The question asked for a definition of "embedded artificial intelligence." The answer gave a definition of "embedded artificial intelligence." It's contrived,  easily Googleable, and adds somewhat irrelevant information that wasn't requested - but most content from new contributors is that way. It is not unambiguous, and I've always thought it was best to give people the benefit of the doubt instead of just deleting whatever doesn't look quite right.

Answer (score 25):

> The first post is a high quality answer with minor formatting issues I would've liked to fix. People who "aren't actually reviewing the tasks" might see the URL and jump to conclude that it's spam. Except it's clearly a string template, and **that same URL is contained in the question** and was only copied into the answer. Therefore, this user's answer was **definitely not spam** and was wrongly flagged and deleted in the first place!

Nope, not quite: look at the comma after *"the 'id' variable between 'Contact' and 'view'"*: it contains a link to `https://mrjoneorganics.com/product/moringa-powder/`, which I haven't clicked but sounds pretty irrelevant and spammy to me.  I'm not sure where they got the text from, but that link disguised on a small punctuation character makes it clear that it's spam.

These are genuinely hard to spot in the default UI; I use [a userscript that makes short links more obvious](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#expand-short-links):

[image: A screenshot of the userscript in action, making the link buried behind a single comma character much more obvious (and Christmasy, since it uses a red-and-green color scheme).]

> The second audit does contain a hyperlink to an individual's website, but it otherwise gives exactly what the question asked for.

Okay, let's see if that could possibly have been posted in good faith.  Is the link relevant in any way to the concept of Artificial Intelligence, which is the text that the link is on?

> [image: Screenshot of website with text: Hello I am RIYA FATHIMA Digital Marketing Strategist in Kannur "Let's grow together"]

...nope.  Looks like pure spam.

> Instead of recommending deletion, I determined it was best to simply remove the link and keep the answer. Is that not reasonable? After further scrutiny, I now suspect the answer is AI generated, but I cannot objectively justify that suspicion. In any case, I don't think it's fair to audit reviewers on the ability to identify content potentially from AIs or know exactly the protocol for handling it.

Please see [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/165261) for an explanation of why editing spam posts is not a good solution.  There are plenty of reasons, but a few that are especially relevant here are:

1. giving spammers reputation allows them to continue to post spam answers that may slip under the radar,
2. editing spam out doesn't alert moderators to spammers that need to be stopped, and
3. the text is generally plagiarized or AI-generated (this looks AI-generated).  The point isn't to identify if it's AI-generated or plagiarized or whatever; **the point is to identify that it's *definitely spam*, flag it, and remove it entirely**, as spammers are pretty reliably not writing high-quality original answers.

Comment: All of this said: if you acknowledge that you'll keep an eye out for sneaky spam links and flag spam posts rather than trying to edit them going forward, I'm happy to consider the audits as having accomplished their education goal (yeah, the condescending messaging is unfortunate, sorry about that...) and lift the review suspension.

Comment: I'm glad you buried that olive-branch of forgiveness in a comment so it wouldn't stop people like me from upvoting this great answer!

Comment: Question of the day: Is @CodyGray starting a review (un)suspension war with their fellow mod?

Comment: There are plenty of users to review suspend, @rene; I wouldn't have to work *nearly* that hard. Also, it's genuinely difficult for me to find anything Ryan does or says that I disagree with.

Comment: Do we have a feature request to make links hidden like that (or in general) more obvious by any chance?

Comment: Not much we can do, @Abdul, as the `<blink>` tag is deprecated and not supported by modern browsers. If we *were* going to do something, it would probably make more sense to block the posting of these single-character links...

Comment: @CodyGray I was more thinking along the lines of [adding an icon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_links#including_icons_on_links). Although yes it does make more sense to just block single character links, although would that work with zero width spaces (Probably need to filter those out or something)?

Comment: @ABabin - Both should be deleted, the answer was low quality for answering spam, the question should be deleted for being spam. You attempted to improve a deleted contribution so you failed the audit. You didn’t identify that correct review action for either review, and since they were both audits, you are temporarily suspended from performing additional reviews incorrectly. Looking at the question it does not actually contain the spam, only the answer does, thus making the answer spam.

Comment: @RyanM I accept that 2nd should be deleted, but I still don't think it's fair to audit reviewers for not knowing this gray area (not that it's AI generated but that one slightly spammy link in an otherwise good looking answer doesn't warrant an attempt to salvage the post). It feels more like a silly "gotcha" trap than a genuine attempt to ensure people are doing what they're supposed to, *which I was*.

Comment: @ABabin - Properly identifying ChatGPT content is now something reviewers should be able to identify. I was immediately able to identify that the second answer was generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: @ABabin - We are talking about the comma turned into a link not the url between the href. For a community not to delete spam, it must be flagged as spam by more than 2 users. The embedded link, the comma, was spam for moringa powder.

Comment: I see it now and accept that I was mistaken, but holy cow, I literally stared at that answer for 10 minutes and didn't see the one tiny hyperlinked comma. If it wasn't an audit, I would've seen it when I tried to edit.

Comment: Is there any way to view the markdown of a post in the Low Quality Answers queue without editing it?

Comment: @ABabin Unfortunately, not without clicking the link at the top of the review and editing it outside of the review.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Right, which no one would ever have *any* reason to do unless they were afraid it was an audit and didn't want to be penalized merely for attempting to improve an answer.

Comment: @ABabin - You should get in the habit of opening the question in another tab.  The review system has a lot of strengths and weaknesses, opening the question in another tab, resolves some of those weaknesses.

Comment: @SecurityHound Do you think it is fair to audit and suspend people on whether or not they've learned to jump through the right hoops in order compensate for the weaknesses of the platform they're providing free labor for? Is it against the rules to *merely consider* editing a post that doesn't outright scream that it contains easily removable spam?

Comment: @ABabin To be clear, I think that the site should have a read-only show-markdown feature as well (not unlike the suggested edits queue). Might be worth asking about if nobody has already.

Comment: @SecurityHound Now that I think about it, when you open a review audit post in another tab, wouldn't you see that it was already flagged and deleted? Doing that for every review makes the whole audit system completely pointless.

Comment: @ABabin doing that for every review *does* make it completely pointless. There are those who feel audits are a "teaching" tool, however at best they teach you that the audit system, and reviewing as a whole, is deeply flawed.

Comment: @KevinB I think I understand now why few people participate and there is so much backlog.

Comment: I don't think of the audits as a teaching tool, but they are one tool to flag people who may need pointers in one specific area.  In general I think the audit system is pretty poor and could use improvement, especially if we will need a large number of additional reviewers for Staging Ground.  These audits happened to be correct, but they didn't _explain_ the logic to the reviewer who hit them, so they did not provide any education until the reviewer came to Meta for an explanation.