# I didn't pass the First Post review queue test

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, first-post-review

As this is about [the specific question I faced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447679/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-job-name-getprojectmetadata-does-not-exist/60101207#60101207), I'm not sure any of the previous answers help me.

In this question, the answerer suggest downgrading a specific library to a previous version, without:

- pointing to an issue/bug tracker with additional information
- explaining why the specific version has to be used (or not, maybe it doesn't need to be that specific version)
- In general, future proofing the answer so it is helpful for as many people as possible, not only the OP.

I wanted to leave a respectful comment, such as *"Please elaborate as to why this is the case, perhaps linking to a documentation or bug report"*

Bear in mind I do not fully understand the question, nor the answer, but it was my assumption that I didn't have to.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits

Comment: @yivi Oh, I didn't realize this was such a big issue. I'm glad I'm not alone, but now I feel maybe I didn't properly search meta for a satisfactory answer.

Comment: If you search for "failed audit comment" you'll get a couple of hits. But search is not infallible.

Comment: @yivi Not to look hurt or anything, but that's somewhat embarrassing. All questions I found where specific and it didn't look like a generic answer was lurking within. And that might be my mistake: thinking instead of reading. Thanks for the SO lesson.