# Appeal for suspension due to commenting on an question that doesn't have any code

Tags: support, status-declined, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review, specific-audit

I got suspended for reviewing for 4 days due to [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27180491). I didn't expect that clarifying a question with no code would get me suspended. (I only commented on the question). I was asking what programming language the OP wanted their problem to be solved in and what they have tried to solve it. Please remove the suspension I got so I could help the community more. Thank you.

Flagging a question would show this, his question does not pass this criteria:

> [image]

Here is the picture of my review page:

> [image]

Comment: The question got 3 downvotes a while ago. IIRC, aren't downvotes supposed to make a post ineligible for known-good-audits? [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27037731) also failed this audit

Comment: Yes. I think this was a mistake so I posted it here. I hope this issue would have enough traffic and upvotes to bring this to the moderator's attention.

Comment: also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: That is true. Comments shouldn't get you suspended. They can help the improve the question even if the question would pass stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: @gnat that doesn't answer my question. I want to retract the suspension I got. I believe this is a mistake from the system and they shouldn't suspend you for commenting. The post above doesn't fit *The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem*

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits

Comment: It’s always a good idea to view the question itself before performing the response to any review item

Comment: I did look at the question. That is why I'm asking him what programming language he wants it to be in and what he has tried to solve it. The question doesn't show any of his attempts to solve it nor what programming language he wants it to be solved in.

Comment: Title: "Appeal for suspension due to commenting on an **answer** that doesn't have any code" - I though you reviewed a question?

Comment: Which **Answer** did you comment on? On a side note: Why should a Question on an algorithm have a language tag? They can be answered using pseudocode. Unfortunately some user think that unless there's code in a post, then it doesn't belong. However this particular post is about runtime, which I believe is very relevant to practical programming. I also do not think that it should be closed due to lack of research. It's basically asking **howto** do it in O(n logn). If they don't know how to do it, how can you expect them to show what they did?

Comment: I tried what you said and it did **not** trigger a failed audit! I tried with this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27199376). I opened up the post in another window (since I can't see the Answers inside the review of a Question). Then I commented on the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63826219/12695027) by [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769).. (1/2)

Comment: ..as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9rTq.png). Then I went back and refreshed the audit.. and nothing. No failed audit, no activating the "I'm Done" button. Then I pressed "No Action Needed" and passed the review 6 minutes after I placed the comment. After passing the audit, I went back and removed my comment. (2/2)

Comment: I changed the title. I made a mistake there. I'm not sure why it didn't give you a failed audit but then I got one. Commenting on the question got me suspended. Some people have experienced the same too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: @Uni Yes. But that is different, and I think it's because it's assumed that you would only comment on a post if there's something wrong with it. It will register your actions on the post both within the review and outside the review. Any action (on the reviewing post itself only) will trigger the "I'm Done" button. But if you do the action outside the review, I believe you'll have to just refresh it for the review to notice your actions. I usually always open up the post on the side, especially if I'm reviewing an Answer.

Comment: its true that I could open the question in a new tab and comment but I can't just press I'm done if I think there is something that can be improved right?

Comment: If it's an audit, you cannot open up the post on the side and comment on it :) The review will notice and (at least it you refresh) you'll fail it. There are generally only two things that can come out of a review. 1. The post should be flagged. 2. The post is fine.  If a post should be closed, you're not suppose to just comment on it. Then you're suppose to flag it, and if you like also comment on it to explain what is wrong or missing. Middle ground is with some Answers that are not to be flagged, but very poor where a comment or a downvote should be done.

Comment: These posts helped me when I started reviewing: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/), [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/) and [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/) and going through all the pages in the help center about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)..
and [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It should have been closed as "too broad" if anything at all. Bad audit. The review audits have been broken for many years & they will not get fixed. The solution is to stop doing reviews.

Comment: I really hoped the moderator would help me solved this but I got declined instead. The 4 days suspension has already worn off today.

Comment: Contra other comments here, I don't see a significant issue with the question. It's very explicitly asking about a language-agnostic problem in a language-agnostic way (which is on topic, per how it was tagged). The point is explicitly about coming up with the algorithm for the task, which in turn is well defined, and specifically about coming up with something with lower complexity than the naive approach of repeatedly searching one list for the index of a value from the other.

Answer (score 6):

Declined. Here are your recently failed audits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26987537 [No action needed]
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27052002 [No action needed]
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27180491 [Reviewed]

Comment: I made a mistake on the first two links provided. Out of the hundred posts I reviewed the past month. Those posts are one month ago. The last post is the one I'm appealing for. I got suspended for 3 days already from the mistake I've made in the last two posts. I've only failed one audit then got suspended for 4 days. https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27180491 is where I've commented to clarify his question and got suspended immediately.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Considering this user seems to have fallen foul of this failure of the SO platform https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment I think it would be fair to reverse this suspension.

Comment: So what happened here, did your suspension ultimately get lifted?

Comment: @T-Heron Thank you for your concern about my suspension. My suspension is still not lifted. I think Samuel Liew will comment/reply when he will lift my suspension.

Comment: I know 4 days seems like forever.  It can can get addicting reviewing stuff, as it is also a good learning experience a you get to see, what new questions are people bringing to the site.  I've personally been suspended 4 times I think, with the last one occurring about three years ago and lasting 30 days!  Don't worry, this too shall pass.

Comment: thanks @T-Heron. I could wait for this but then I just don't want to get suspended up to a month or the point that I can't review anymore when I make more mistakes.

Comment: @Uni well... there is nothing that can be done about that. As you have noticed, you are being rate limited currently, it only takes one audit failure to net you an extended suspension. This suspension being reversed is nog going to change that fact.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby. The suspension has worn off today. I think its best for me to stop reviewing for a long time so the rate limit resets.