# Why was this software support question considered "high quality"?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

[Link to the audit here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27707360)

I failed an audit that was asking about software support for [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) by leaving a comment.

Why is a software support question appropriate for Stack Overflow and not an Xcode-related [subreddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit#Subreddits)?

Comment: This is a developer tool. Asking for support with developer tools is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Failed an audit because you left a comment?! What if you were complimenting it?!

Comment: You aren't supposed to leave chatty comments while reviewing, @Ann.

Comment: Semi-related: [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260803/2821954)

Comment: [How do I exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270)

Comment: @AnnZen that's a wll known problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306916, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260810

Comment: Completely unrelated, it still bothers me leaving a comment is enough to trigger an audit fail. There's lots of valid reasons to comment on a good question

Comment: @Zoe I think bad question audits will just reject your comment with the message "This is an audit", so it isn't even consistent.

Comment: @Haem Bad question audits may or may not accept the comment. I remember one of the queues accepting them (as in resulting in a passed audit), but I don't remember which. Definitely inconsistent, so the best move [is to not play](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js)

Comment: It's not really a high quality Q&A, just a popular problem that many people seem to have. Certainly useful, but I would hesitate to call it high quality. It might be another discussion how score and quality correlate.

Comment: @Trilarion it'd be a glorious day when all people would actually vote based on quality and not based on feelings regarding reward and punishment.

Comment: @Zoe FWIW I recently [requested this to change to opposite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354290/165773) (ie trigger audit pass instead of failure) when they collected feedback for coming improvements in review suspensions, "One of current criteria involved in triggering review suspension is blatantly wrong and needs to be corrected. Respective feature requests are hanging ignored for many years despite strong community support..." etc

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's not how it works here. We don't compare questions in order to make the decisions consistent. One question and its state has no influence whatsoever on another question. We just have rules/guidelines and meta to discuss errors, inconsistencies or solving disputes. Errors can happen. Regarding that other question you linked: it's programming-software related but it's not clear which software, to me it looks like a software recommendation question, which would be offtopic, even for programming-related software. Incidentally I was one of the close voters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very well known that if you up your phone to a version of iOS that your version of Xcode doesn't support, then if you try to build to that phone from that copy of Xcode, you'll get this mysterious alert about the iPhone not being available. That alert wording has been there for years. And the larger fact — that an older version of Xcode doesn't magically support a newer version of iOS — has *always* been the case.

The correct procedure is: don't do that. Don't update your development phone's iOS version until there is a version of Xcode that *does* support that version of iOS. There is usually, at the least, a *beta* of Xcode that meets that requirement. Currently, there is a *release* version of Xcode meets the OP's stated requirement.

From an SO point of view, the trouble is that the same question keeps getting asked again and again — not just [iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device. / iOS 14.2 - Xcode 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736953/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device-ios-14-2-xcode-12-1) but also, say, [Could not locate device support files, iPhone is not available. Xcode 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854524/could-not-locate-device-support-files-iphone-is-not-available-xcode-12) — and some people are taking advantage of this to give the *same answer* over and over again, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64737156/341994 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854525/341994 (they are almost word for word the same answer).

So in my view this *is* a bad situation on Stack Overflow and the question *should* be penalized in some way.

Comment: That's fair - sounds like this question is a duplicate. Not sure what the best dupe target is - perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/61863826/1709587.

Comment: What do you suggest as the canonical question?

Comment: The OP didn't do a silly thing. Falling into a hole that you didn't see ahead of you doesn't become silly just because many other people have fallen into the same hole. Perhaps they should have found the answer without posting the question, but the primary culprit is the person responsible for the hole being there in the first place...

Comment: @PeterMortensen I would say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863826/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device

Comment: @MichaelKay Fair enough, I'll delete that sentence; nothing else I'm saying depends on it.

Answer (score 40):

Questions about using IDEs are on-topic, including questions about Xcode. That the community broadly takes this view is evidenced by the [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) tag existing and having 147k questions, many with large numbers of upvotes. It's also corroborated by the wording in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - ..., or
> - ..., or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

That *by itself* doesn't necessarily truly make it "high quality", of course, but your specific reason for objecting to it isn't a good one.

As for why this question was selected as an audit, that'll be because it was highly upvoted and had no downvotes - though it seems that it's now received a couple of downvotes due to the meta effect, so won't be used as an audit again.

Finally, for what it's worth, the question *does* seem genuinely good to me. There are maybe some minor nits to pick - I see one typo, for instance - but it clearly articulates the problem (the asker gets the quoted error message every time they try to run their app on a device) and what triggered the problem to appear (upgrading iOS to 14.2 on their device). What's more, it's evidently a common problem, since there are 4000 views and 29 upvotes - all in less than 3 weeks. And finally, it has clear answers, explaining the cause (the latest version of Xcode doesn't yet support the latest version of iOS) and providing a workaround (installing a community-written patch for Xcode to add support for iOS 14.2).

All of that plainly seems like good content to me; we've got useful answers here to a programming problem that has affected many readers. Why wouldn't we want it here?