# "stop and listen" false alert when adding a comment

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Reviewing first-time posts, I got a "STOP AND LISTEN" audit failure after I had added a comment suggesting to improve the question. (Next thing I wanted to do is click on "Looks OK", but I got an audit failure saying the post was "high quality".)

I got the impression that adding a comment is always counted as something negative.
Shouldn't the "STOP AND LISTEN" wait until I pressed a button (other than adding a comment)?

Comment: I believe the audit exactly worked as intended. You didn't pay attention, the post doesn't need an edit, despite you advised to do so in a comment. The correct action would have been _looks ok_.

Comment: @JeanneDark https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307082/6607497 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262511/6607497 somehow answers the question, meaning I was right, the system was wrong.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ How do you know the post does not need an edit without having read the comment I wanted to add? Also I *did not* press a "needs edit button"; I did not press any button yet. That's what I wrote.

Comment: To me, if you are saying that the question could do with an edit you are by definition saying that it doesn't "look ok". If it needs an edit, you should be choosing the option to state that either the OP or the community need to edit it (depending on whom can perform that edit). A question that needs editing;,either for formatting by the community or by the OP to add clarity, is not "OK".

Comment: Things are not always that clear: There are questions that pass the tests performed by others (are "OK"), but still lack essential information. Maybe take https://stackoverflow.com/q/65863743/6607497 for an example.