# Audits in the close vote review queue don't allow to post a comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, vote-to-close

I was going through the close vote queue and got a question for which I was intending to cast a close vote but only after leaving a comment (it was a question that would have belonged to another Stack Exchange site, so I just wanted to link the site in the comment).

**But**: when I hit enter to post the comment I got a message "this is an audit", and the post was gone, so I missed the chance to pass one audit, I guess.

Very minor issue but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Before that feature was implemented leaving a comment on an audit worked like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: @rene I see, that didn't make sense. Still, ideally leaving a comment shouldn't prejudice the chance of passing or failing audit

Comment: They're not designed for you to pass or fail, just to see if you were paying attention. If you left a comment, you were paying attention.

Comment: There is a user script for Close vote/ reopen votes and triage reviews. It helps you identify the status of the post