# Comments cause failed first post review

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits

Going through the 1st post review queue, I came across this post (which happened to be an audit post)

[image]

Now this answer, while providing a valid counter-example to the question, asserts that the answer to the question is yes for *all* languages, while providing an example using c/cpp features, despite the question specifically asking for a javascript solution.

Seeing that the answer wasn't blatantly wrong, I decided to add a comment pointing out that it isn't necessarily true for all languages, as the highest voted comment did, causing me to fail the audit.

Now my issue with this is that audits are being failed on comments, assuming that all comments are going to be of a negative nature, which is definitely not the case. 
Is there any reason that commenting on a question/answer should not be treated as a neutral option, since it is impossible to determine whether a comment is supporting or rejecting a post without analyzing its contents?

Comment: IIRC, it was different once. And then people wrote an extensive comment in a review... only to find that the post was an audit.