# Automatic reload of edited questions in review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I had the following unpleasant experience now several times: I write a longer comment to a question in the Review queue (e.g. First Posts). While I am collecting links for the OP, someone edits the question. While outside the Review queue this is only shown as a warning "This question has been edited", in the review queue the page automatically reloads after a few seconds, meaning my comment draft is lost. Is there a chance to change this behaviour? Or am I not aware of a setting to prevent an automatic reload in the Review queue?

Comment: I should warn you: I recently [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18976561) for simply leaving a comment on a question _that happened to be an audit_. I would just not do it all at. [See the relevant meta post on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260803/5781745).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Bizarre system behaviour, favouring roboreviewer. But I won't refrain from commenting. If they punish me for doing, what a reviewer is supposed to do - so be it.