# Failed Audit for commenting

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25121802) audit, for commenting the exact same comment already having more than 20 upvotes (which wasn't visible during audit):

> Please include the compilation error message.

I did not upvote or downvote because it seemed like a textbook question instead of a real problem faced by the poster, but I wanted to give the poster the benefit of the doubt by asking for clarification using a comment.

Looking at other such questions, it seems like commenting isn't useful without upvote or downvote. Is that the case?

Comment: [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25121465) I failed for commenting, even though I intended to upvote after commenting. Feels bad when you spend 15 minutes carefully reading a long answer but are accused of 'Not paying attention'. Maybe the audit should fail or succeed only on selecting `I'm done`?

Comment: As an aside: If you were going to upvote... why comment at all?

Comment: @yivi I didn't realize my comment wasn't posted! Again, bad! Posted now, you can see the comment to get the context but essentially I asked for some examples of something they mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @yivi  Just because an answer is good doesn't mean there can't be a subtle point you'd like clarification of, or think the answer would benefit if was expanded.

Comment: Didn't we had a feature that leaving a comment never caused a failed audit? Or was that not implemented on first posts reviews?

Comment: @dan I don’t think I said otherwise. I was just asking the OPs reason for wanting to comment.