# Specific First Posts question

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

The First Posts question is https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25577126

I'm going to skip it because I don't know the answer.

My options are:

**Valid/No Action Needed**: I don't think this is appropriate because the question contains a "please Help Me." so at minimum should have a noise reduction edit. There is no research effort from OP.

**Upvote**: I don't think this is appropriate because there is no research effort.

**Downvote**: I don't think this is appropriate because though there is no research effort, the question could be answered and may be useful in the future for anyone who needs to pipe console output or needs command line arguments from this program.

**Other flags**: *Spam*, no. *Rude*, no. *Duplicate*, I've searched, it's not.

**Should be closed flags**: aren't appropriate because it's clear what is asked for (to me) so has clarity. However it shows no research effort and has a clear "can you do this for me" style of asking. *Needs more focus* or *opinion based* could fit but I'm not sure because the question, of which I think there's one, *can* be answered. As mentioned, it could be a useful question for the site.

Comment: 1) You can edit the questions from inside the queue. 2) This question should be closed because it shows no research effort and because it lacks at least some code to see what op already has done. I'd go with Should be closed > Needs details or clarity.

Comment: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

Comment: You can vote however you like, but that a question does not show any research is a canonical downvote reason. Also, as BDL mention you can help editing while in the queue, but for this question is would be a mistake. Suggesting an edit for a question that needs to be closed so the author can improve it it's a waste of effort for everyone, and a disservice to the post owner.

Answer (score 5):

> **Downvote:** I don't think this is appropriate because though there is no research effort, the question could be answered and may be useful in the future for anyone who needs to pipe console output or needs command line arguments from this program.

Your reasoning is incorrect here. Downvoting doesn't mean "this question is unanswerable" (that's what close votes/flags are for), it means "this isn't a good question." And it isn't, so downvoting is absolutely an appropriate response. Remember you can always reverse downvotes later if the question is edited into better shape.

As for a close flag, while you might be able to understand *generally* what they're asking for, it's unclear to me what *specifically* their problem is. I think either "needs focus" or "needs details or clarity" is appropriate here as well.

Another option you haven't mentioned is to leave a comment instructing the user on what they need to do to improve the question. Or if you really do know what their specific problem is, you can suggest an edit yourself to improve the question, which will count as a review action if you do it from inside the queue. This is usually the ideal resolution when it's possible, since the main purpose of the First Posts queue is to help provide guidance to new users.

Comment: The only potential problem with leaving a comment is that you risk [failing an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment/262511#262511), a bug that still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @ouflak Yeah, that's kind of a ridiculous oversight. But if it's a bad question that needs to be improved, then there shouldn't be any risk of audit failure (either that or you misjudged its badness and would have failed the audit regardless).

Comment: Hi @JohnMontgomery, the tooltip for Downvoting is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Though I'm more enlightened now after reading related meta posts such as [when to downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question), my interpretation of this tooptip replaces the ; with 'and'. This particular question fails the "it is unclear" or "not useful" tests therefore a downvote is not appropriate.