# First posts audit dispute

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I was pinged on this First Posts audit when adding a comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26448020

I was trying to suggest that the question might be more appropriate to send to the support team/forum for the software product in question (Firebase Services plugin).

Apparently some people here knew that an update was available, which is great, but the question still seems off-topic to me.

Could someone confirm that my analysis is valid, or explain why such a question is totally appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: It is directly related to tools primarily used in programming (Android Studio), specifically about upgrading an IDE, why would it be off-topic? That said, you still shouldn't fail an audit for commenting... one day we'll stop getting these posts... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: Ok, thanks Nick. I'll adjust my feedback to future questions accordingly. I also voted up the question & answer you linked. However, since this has apparently been an issue since 2014, I won't hold my breath for a change ;)