# Was this a bad audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing First Posts just now, and I failed an audit:

[image]

I didn't think it was a very good answer, and I attempted to comment to let the poster know, which the system rightly (in this case) interpreted as me thinking it was a bad answer.

I guess the system regards the answer as high quality because it has a lot of upvotes, but I don't think it's that good of an answer.

Comment: That's technically plagiarism if it's copy-pasted. The lack of a URL means it fails the attribution requirement for external sources. Even if that was fixed, copying the entirety of an external source with no original content is [also against the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.". As for commenting causing audit failure, that's by design for whatever reason (it's completely stupid; audits suck)

Comment: @Zoe what is plagiarism? The answer?

Comment: if it's copied, yeah. I can't find any matches though, so it might just be bad phrasing

Comment: @BDL No it doesn't. I don't particularly care about whether the act of commenting causes a failed audit. Also the post you linked to is a duplicate of [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment?rq=1)

Comment: @gnat The accepted answer says "You've done the right thing in bringing attention to this poor audit by posting this question". Have *I* done the right thing by posting about this audit? If my question gets closed as a duplicate, does that mean I needn't have bothered?

Comment: @James a duplicate is _not_ a bad thing. It adds sign posts for other users _and_ answers the question. That's why questions closed as duplicates don't get automatically deleted (IIRC)

Comment: @Nick ok, thanks for letting me know!