# High Quality Example Posts in Review Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

To be honest, I don't know whether this belongs here or not. I stumbled upon this question in my review-queue and think the evaluation is rather unfair. My review was to comment saying, that a link to the forum entry would be great. Are these samples automatically selected? If yes I can report that I encountered a lot of bad answers marked correctly and upvoted (i.e. link only, bad format, only code block).

[image]

Don't get me wrong, I see that this seems to have been the right answer and I'm glad someone could help the questioner, but I wouldn't say this is especially a high-quality post. Where can someone report such an exemplary post as "not-exemplary" or (not saying this one is) actually low quality?

Comment: Yes this does answer my question @cigien Thank you very much. My personal problem here would be that I don't necessarily would want to downvote or delete this post. It seems to have answered the question just not in a high quality manner. But if there are no other answers, I wouldn't want to be the one removing the only -in most cases even accepted- answer.

Comment: Removing an answer as a review audit is quite different from deleting that answer. If you don't think the question even deserves a downvote then I think it's sufficiently high-quality to be a review audit, and shouldn't be removed. Note that a review audit doesn't mean it's an extremely good answer, or that it couldn't be improved at all.

Comment: That's a horrible review audit, I agree. That needed to be *at minimum* edited, almost certainly downvoted. Unfortunately, yes, these audits are automatically selected. There's no way for moderators to curate the list. Although I've now [corrected the problems with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65329297).

Comment: I mean if I flag it, it will get removed eventually. You might have a point with the sufficiency. There are a lot of meta posts about downvoting and how it is very good, but when I started every downvote on a -from my perspective back then- high-quality answer  I took a lot of time to craft, crushed me. Especially for new users I rather take the time and explain to them what really helps the community and what not...

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodyGray I just read up on the process, hope that it somehow gets adjusted in the future.

Comment: I would love if moderators could manually specify posts to become review audits. I also hope that becomes a thing. In the meantime, all I can tell you is that I know it's frustrating to fail a bad audit, but it takes more than one failed audit to be suspended from reviewing, and *hopefully* these bad audits are relatively rare. If you are hit by another one, and end up suspended, please let a moderator know, either via Meta or elsewhere. We'll be happy to remove your suspension. And keep dealing with these bad audits as advised, outside of the review queues. Thanks for your help reviewing!

Comment: If I understood your action by "to comment", also related: [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260803/2821954)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes this is exactly what I experienced.