# Why does this count as a failed review audit?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I was given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874794/efficient-way-of-making-time-increment-strings/65874955#65874955) to review in the First Posts category. All I did was leave a comment saying

> Please explain what your code does and how it does it. Also, please don't copy people's answers.

That seemed fair enough to me.

It was counted as failing [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28213520). This resulted in me getting review banned for more than 2 months.

I don't understand this at all. First, my comment seemed pretty legitimate to me. I see no reason that it would be harmful to anyone. Second, what's wrong with leaving a comment? I don't even know if the system detects what my comment is. What if it was a comment complimenting the answer?

On a more unrelated note, my last failed review audit was more than a month ago, yet it still counted for my review ban. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Rest assured that I will not be reviewing First Posts on this site again until this bug is fixed.

EDIT: HOORAY, it's fixed!!! I just tried to leave a comment on a review audit of a good answer and it counted as PASSING!!!

Comment: Yeah, this is actually a known bug. One thing you could do is open the answer in a new tab. If the votes or anything else is different, then you know it's an audit and you can skip it.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated  Yes, but as you can see the last question about this was more than 6 years ago yet this problem still hasn't been fixed. I think it's time to finally destroy this bug.

Comment: But that's up to SE devs; I'm sure they'll fix it when they get time. You can also vote before you leave a comment to counter it.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated Well, unfortunately I now have to wait another 2 months to review again.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 You can spend that time learning Haskell or become the next regex guru ;)

Comment: I'm not so sure they'll fix it. It's not a bug in the sense that the code isn't working right -- right now it's working as designed. It's a design bug because they chose (and choose) to assume that if you're commenting on the post, it's ["an explanation for why you're downvoting or flagging."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260810/7795130) So the comment is always considered a negative action on a review audit, and that answer was considered good, so a negative action on a good answer fails the audit. They'll need to reconsider that logic to make a difference here.

Comment: That's correct; it is not a bug. You should almost never be posting a comment when reviewing posts. Comments don't solve problems (flags do), and review isn't for kibitzing.

Comment: @CodyGray But oftentimes I just don't like the answer and it's not bad enough for a flag. Then I try to avoid downvoting (because I don't want to lose reputation) by posting a comment instead about how it could be improved.

Comment: Please do not try to avoid downvoting. Comments and downvotes serve two very different purposes.

Comment: @CodyGray hard when you have 1k reputation, or 2k in my case. I need every bit as I want privileges.