# Got an un-deserved review ban for a poor (?) review

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension, specific-audit

I just got a review ban because of [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32211459).

Only the first three options were available, and I clicked "Share feedback", intending to add a comment to the OP. But the popup dialog never showed up, and I was directed to the screen of "bad review, you are banned".

As you can see in the post's question, it’s about scraping [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) pages, and the in-review answer was a laconic:

> I Had this problem too. Now I solve it with this url
>
> https://www.instagram.com/p/CFr6G-whXxp/?__a=1&__d=dis

Maybe I am wrong, but I think this answer - although it was a legitimate one - tricked SO's algorithms to consider it a spam, and also led in considering my review wrong. That's why I am adding the `bug` tag in this post.

Can I have your thoughts please? Is "share feedback" in this answer a wrong one?

I got an 8-day review ban for this.

Comment: What were "the first three options?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey options were "looks ok", "edit" and "share feedback" which triggers a submenu with other options

Comment: If you had opened the question in another tab the fact it was an audit would have been obvious. There isn’t anything wrong with that answer. You failed the audit because providing feedback on an answer that has nothing wrong with it is the incorrect choice. You also clearly failed more than a single audit of your review banned.

Comment: On the contrary, there's plenty wrong with that answer.  It's "link-only," the link itself is a bad link, and it's hard to imagine how anyone would get any help from an Instagram post.  A spam flag would have been appropriate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey have you checked the post's question? its about scraping instagram page, the guy who i was reviewing his answer suggested to add some parameters to the URL

Comment: 12 upvotes not a single downvote. It probably should have downvotes but it doesn’t so there isn’t anything wrong with it. One doesn’t get a 8 day review ban after a single incorrect audit.

Comment: And there you have it.  Question context has always been a problem with the review queue for answers; even for moderators.  If you look at the review, you'll see that there isn't even a link to the question to cross-check it.

Comment: @SecurityHound as far as i remember, clicking "share feedback" opens up a submenu with options, you are not commiting your review to anything, you can close the submenu dialog. i didnt have the chance to do that, i was led to the "bad review" response

Comment: It would have been better if the poster had supplied some explanation with their answer to provide some context.  The proper response is "share feedback," a response which apparently caused the audit to fail.

Comment: All that said, were you review-banned?  Is this your first review failure?  If so, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  It happens to the best of us occasionally.

Comment: Share feedback results in an automatic comment suggesting the contribution needs to be improved. It’s not bug because picking share feedback never results in that dialogue being displayed. It might be a bad audit but the contribution has 12 upvotes. I would argue the “share feedback” is the incorrect option.  Likewise, the review ban, was the result of failing multiple review audits and this single bad review audit was the last one that was failed.  [Does it change the fact other audits were failed or “share feedback” was the incorrect choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIKMS.jpg)

Comment: If "Share Feedback" results in an automatic comment, then this is a training and documentation problem.  That's not what I would expect a "share feedback" button to do; in the absence of any other instruction, I would expect it to allow me to leave a comment below the answer.  I've been here for years and I didn't know that's how the button worked, although to be fair, this is one of many reasons I seldom visit the queues.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, 8 days, because there was another review failed: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32187236), for which i still think the "looks OK" was a valid selection - the answer was not a spam or offensive, i dont know if it was wrong or irrelevant, that would be for the OP to validate.

Comment: That one has several problems.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thats questionable i guess but anyway, i am here to discuss the latest one. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SecurityHound: As to the upvotes; I don't even look at them in the review queues.  I've seen the review queue deliberately alter the votes to trick users during audits.

Comment: @ilias-sp: The only safe way to do this is to look at the question if there is any doubt.  That would have clarified "the latest one."

Comment: I've switched the [bug] tag out. I understand your intention, but share feedback failing a "known good" audit is [status-by-design] (related: [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](/q/412271/15497888)). If you'd like this to be changed that would be a [feature-request] and/or [discussion] but this is not a [bug] in the implementation. A "this post appears to be spam" banner on a "known good" audit is also part of the review audit system and is not indicative that the post was considered to be spam.

Comment: @RobertHarvey true, but sharing feedback would be also fine - writing a short comment to the author that his answer would be better with some more text explaining what he added etc etc.

Comment: It would seem that the best way to do that is to do it on the actual post, outside of the audit.

Comment: @HenryEcker maybe i remember things wrong, but isnt "share feedback" meant to pop-up a submenu with other options which you can always cancel if you dont see an option that suits you? if its not a action that you commit with a single-click, then i dont see why i was prohibited from "cancelling"

Comment: [Not during an audit.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412282/102937)

Comment: For reference, the other failed audit leading to the ban was https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32187236

Comment: @RobertHarvey so "share feedback" does what in this case? adds some automated message? i am confusing the option with similar option from other review queues, and since i am banned cannot see the menus anyway :)

Comment: That's why I recommend you use the original post to leave feedback.  Note that the post @HenryEcker linked [complains about this nuance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412271/why-did-i-fail-this-first-question-review-audit-after-choosing-sharing-feedback#comment873325_412282).

Comment: @RyanM i already shared that. I still think its a legitimate answer that the OP has the technical knowledge to evaluate if its useful / solving the issue or not. But we can focus in the review that i opened "this" post for.

Comment: To be clear, there's a material difference between "I failed this audit" and "I failed this audit, and also a previous one."

Comment: @RobertHarvey "*If you look at the review, you'll see that there isn't even a link to the question to cross-check it*" there are *two* places to see the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RCko.png clicking on the title brings you to the post. Clicking on **Question** shows it without leaving the review queue.

Comment: @ilias-sp - Your first audit you failed absolutely isn’t “looks ok”, you might have an argument for the review audit your asking about, but I would argue that an answer with as many votes as it has (which I would again point out would have been known if you had opened in another tab) should have been marked as “looks ok”. Audit system is flawed in that there is only one correct answer. Strange you were review banned after only two failed audits.  However, 8 days suggests, you have been review suspensioned before recently

Comment: The answer could certainly do with an edit to make it not look like a "Me too" answer. The non-URL text is basically noise. Simply changing the text to *"I solved the problem by adding `&__d=dis` as an additional parameter to the URL"* would lilely make it much less contentious, even if it doesn't explain why the solution works.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this:[Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412271) (or any other "share feedback fails audit). It is an old issue, but the company has no time to address this issue, changing voting buttons is more important.

Comment: Here is a clear-cut reason why you should always open up the question in a separate tab. From the review screen you can't see the tags under the question (which is a huge design flaw IMO). Even if it shouldn't, tags do have their own sub-communities with their own standards and you'd have to know those standards if you would want to have a chance of making review choices based only on the review information and not trip an audit. A question which has no programming language tag assigned to it is pretty much going to be the wild west, you can't know where it went IF it is audit.

Answer (score 7):

While having all imaginable signs of a "bad, off-topic, not an answer" post, the answer actually answers the question and provides exactly the right information to the audience of the question.

I would not call it an ideal audit in the regular "you should be paying attention while reviewing" sense - and for other queues you'd probably have a good basis to ask to get this ban lifted. For the [First posts reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review), the guidance is more elaborate—*[How do I use the First answers queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers)*—and checking other answers would have hinted that other answers are somewhat similar. Checking the whole question would actually show that 12 was the real number of votes. Note that I'm quite sure I'd fail that review too as the post does not look like an answer, but rather a "me too" comment (possibly I'd check the question due to the high score, but, as [Robert Harvey commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419175/got-an-un-deserved-review-ban-for-a-poor-review#comment918102_419175), scores on audits are likely to be fake).

Why the post is actually an answer and why quality and votes are so off: The question essentially is "url example.com?param=1 no longer returns details while scraping" and the linked answer gives the modification to make that same URL work again "example.com?param=1&__someother=42".

This information is 100% enough for anyone involved in scraping of that particular site (which is a known and popular activity), thus making it a valuable answer for that particular part of the community. Indeed the answer could be made better by explicitly spelling out the change and removing "me too" portion, but the audience of the question is unlikely to be interested in such superficial improvements.

Note that I totally expect the answer to be updated with similar hacks in the future, but I don’t see any reason for one that scrapes web sites to worry about the answer being readable by other people.

Comment: it is a tricky review, and the under review answer was meant to be classified as "looks OK". But i dont understand why clicking "share feedback" lead to "bad review". 

As i remember - and maybe i am wrong here - "share feedback" opens a submenu that you can cancel, but the design didnt give me this capability, it was immediately considered a bad review.

Comment: @ilias-sp It leads to a bad review, because the company behind all Stack Exchange sites doesn't know anymore what those sites are supposed to be. Quality in posts was a goal, not anymore, so providing feedback to increase the quality is just considered toxic when some other users upvoted the post already (yes, I exaggerate a bit). When you do reviewe, never choose "share feedback" from the review queue, go to the actual post instead, or better, don't do reviews for a company which doesn't want you to do proper reviews.

Comment: @Tom from my experience reviewing several queues, i consider this whole reviewing concept a bad practice; in my opinion, only offensive/rude/racist/spam/etc posts should be removed, all rest should be allowed and handled by upvote/downvote buttons. i am not going to spend any more time on these queues.

Comment: that is best a low quality answer and requires at least some explication why this works

Comment: Even though the answer answers the question, it's not a *good* answer. The First Answers queue is not Triage nor LQP where anything that isn't utter junk is **Looks OK**. Rather, in First Answers, if the post isn't anything other than *perfect*, sharing feedback can be helpful by commenting, editing, or voting. The answer was valuable in the form it was in during ilias-sp's review, but I think it does pretty clearly deserve additional treatment - in which case Share Feedback **was** the right choice.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - It would have been if more people downvoted the answer, but it had so many upvotes, providing feedback to improve the contribution, ended up being the incorrect choice.  Audit would have been passed if the question was opened in another tab.