# Is this a poor audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/35234060). I decided to share feedback, because the answer suggested a Docker solution, but Docker is never mentioned or tagged in the OP. I thought I'd point this out, but there are 14 upvotes, which probably led me to fail the audit.

Is there something I didn't understand?

Comment: The "Share feedback" option on audits is honestly broken. One can easily add a comment even to a good post, yet the audit consider this a negative action.

Comment: Don't forgot there could be things like comments that have since been deleted that have details the OP failed to edit in later too. Because an answer uses a technology not mentioned doesn't mean it's incorrect; sometimes users can correctly infer than information. In truth, as well, part of doing the queues is knowing how to spot audits.

Comment: @ThomA, that's right. I think this is an useful answer, but not closely related to the question. In the everyday scenario, a such comment can improve the overall quality of the site

Comment: Edits are allowed to invalidate other questions, they aren't bound by the rules of each other. Editting a question to invalidate*answers* on that question is a different problem though. The OP is that question is clearly using  docker, as the docker solution worked, so it being tagged correctly is important. We can see the revision history of the question though, so we know whatnot looked like before, and so your question is still valid.

Comment: @ThomA  I actually do not recognize Docker in the OP, so that's  the problem. anyway, thank you :-)

Comment: @pierpy you were right, the accepted answer is an answer which does not involve docker and if the tag was ever there it is no longer. But I think in general you shouldn't try to comment from within a review queue, always open the source question and provide feedback there to circumvent this bit of bad design.

Comment: To add to @Gimby's comment, if you try to open the original post, and you no longer see the post (or see it's deleted if you're above 10k) you know to not waste your time on actions. Audits are not designed to trick you out, just to make sure you're paying attention

Comment: _"an edit to the question has added the docker tag"_ there is no occurrence of [tag:docker] in the [revision history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77314799/revisions), so I think you might be mistaken there, unless it was done by yivi and they corrected it before the edit timeout.

Comment: Related: [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412271/208273)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I decided to share feedback, because the answer suggested a Docker solution, but Docker is never mentioned or tagged in the OP.

The mention of Docker in the answer is circumstantial, at best. The main content of the answer is that the version of Node used by OP might be the cause of the conflict. This could be experienced via using Docker, or it could be experienced by using any other system that automatically calls the latest version, too.

The answer is... not greatly worded, but it is not a *bad* audit, per se. Clicking through and seeing the score was truly 14 and not inflated by the review system should have been your confirmation that this was a 'known good' audit item.

In the meantime, I've revised the answer to help future reviewers avoid thinking this is a bad answer.

> Also, an edit to the question has added the [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag. Why? The edit invalidates my question here.

I'm not sure what you're referring to. The question revision history does not show any instance of a [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag existing on it.

---

All this being said, for what it's worth, the *question* itself is a duplicate of a similar error report posted two hours earlier.

Comment: "Also, an edit to the question has added the docker tag." The audit system will add a tag to the audit to match your tag filter.

Comment: @Laurel OP made the edit complaining about the tag _after_ they failed the audit and posted this question. If the tag existed on the question during the audit, it wouldn't make sense for OP to complain about it _after_ asking here, nor would the remark about "invalidating this question" make any sense.

Comment: I am guessing yivi might have added the docker tag in their revision and removed it within the grace period. Otherwise OP might just be mistaken

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Maybe. OP made their edit about it about 15 minutes after yivi's edit went through, so at most they had to have lagged behind by 10 minutes. Could be possible. Not a big deal either way.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you are right.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for clarifications. For me, that was a 1 rep user answering in a way somewhat useful, but with a completely different tool and approach  :-) 
I wanted to point this out to him.  But, as you mention, the 14 upvotes mean I'm misinterpreting the answer

Comment: But the user doesn't have 1 rep? They have over 500 rep.

Comment: @TylerH the real rep was not visible in that moment. It was 1

Comment: @pierpy - One of the signs it was an audit, when an answer with 8+ upvotes is an audit, it's there to verify you are paying attention and can identify high quality contributions

Comment: "Clicking through and seeing the score was truly 14 and not inflated by the review system should have been your confirmation that this was a 'known good' audit item." ?!? Having to **realize** that **an audit is an audit** in order to pass said audit turns the audit's criteria from "are you paying attention and giving good judgements" to "can you spot the audit" :/

Comment: @CharonX you can simply open the actual Q&A for every review. Back in the days when I did reviews, I always did this though, granted, the “Other answers” and “Question” tabs did not exist back then, so this was the only way to check the context which was missing in the review page. If a reviewer is paying attention rather than rushing through the posts, the time to open a post in a new tab and closing the tab does not affect the overall review time. That’s not meant to imply that the audit system was good as it is today, just that it doesn’t stop reviewers who pay attention.

Comment: @CharonX The line you quoted was in response to OP's confusion about the attributes of the post. The user was shown as 1 rep but the post had a score of 14, so one of those is clearly being manipulated by the system, or the user was banned, either of which cases warrant taking a closer look. On top of that, given this is on the 'First Answers' queue, seeing a post with a score of 14 should be an indicator that either something is off (audit) or this is a post that should receive a "looks good" review (or both, in this case).

Comment: Audits are designed to make sure you are paying attention. The only difference between "paying attention" and "can you spot the audit" is just _how much_ attention you are paying. The takeaway is, if nothing else, at least "pay more attention". That being said, I'm not personally a fan of 'provide feedback' choices resulting in audit failures. It's about an equivalent action to 'edit' in other queues which pass audits no matter whether they're good or bad.

Comment: @CharonX You're not wrong. But there is another quality to the audit system - knowledge of it's existence should help people to keep a slower pace and treat every review with the proper amount of scrutiny. The name of the game is preventing or catching robo reviewing. And there is another too - that "STOP!" message you get when you fail an audit tends to trigger people to not let it go and go to meta. Which is excellent.