# Why does a first question review audit fail me when I select an open-ended option?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I just failed an audit on the first question queue - [this was the audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737118/what-is-a-good-technique-for-compile-time-detection-of-mismatched-preprocessor-d) - and firstly it was an obvious audit because it had no associated user but also I clicked `share feedback` whereupon it instantly failed me. When the feedback option offers the opportunity to provide literally any feedback message, that seems a little prescriptive. The system has no idea what feedback I was going to give. I suspect I would probably have failed for selecting anything but `Looks OK`?

It says "make sure you read and understand why you failed" but I can't see a way that offering feedback that could improve the way a question is framed is a failure condition. It doesn't say what the "right answer" here would have been, so when it is ambiguous like this it just feels like the audit system punches you out of the blue and then shrugs like "should have seen that coming."

Since I have got involved in the review queues more over the last couple of weeks I have hit a few weirdly hostile audit questions that feel more like a deliberately posed puzzle than an attempt to check whether I am paying attention. They're generally quite out of keeping with everything else in the queue so it's pretty clear when one is an audit question and maybe the correct response is to skip them by default. But I would argue that if the correct way to respond to an audit is always to avoid it, there is a problem with the audit system. Why not base the things being audited on successfully resolved audits from the same queue? I'm doing this because I want to help, not because I want to be confounded by trying to double and triple-guess audit questions.

I guess SO has so many people blazing through the review queues that there's no problem with putting some of us off with this approach, but at the very least it would be helpful to have some indication of what the "correct" response would have been on a failure. As things stand it just tells us we're wrong without giving any guidance on how to be right beyond *read and understand* which is what I aim to do before choosing what review response to give.

Comment: What feedback did you feel the question required to help improve it?

Comment: You [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31476312) to [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31502675) be [alone](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31506912) in this case ... 3 others persons failed the same audit, for the same reason ... (so 50% failed)

Comment: Also, this seems related to my suggestion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414819/10952503) (10k+ link) about positive audit that can be bad, and here it seems to be the case

Comment: @Tom I think it does - I don't remember it saying that "share feedback" was an effective close vote, and if that is the case then it should be marked that way rather than as feedback. The idea I had got on First Questions was that we were trying to guide users towards asking questions better. If it warrants closing I can just raise a close vote anyway, though maybe not every reviewer has that right yet.

Comment: @Larnu, How could you, or the system, possibly know what that feedback would be? It would seem that [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment/262511#262511) hasn't been fixed, but has merely been transferred over to the new system.

Comment: I don't know what it is, @ouflak, but by saying that you are giving feedback means that you feel the question needs improvement; hence I am asking what that improvement is. Providing feedback to state "Your question is well formed, well done." is just noise, and shouldn't be posted; if that was the intended feedback then that is why they failed the audit.