# Which part was wrong in my review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I was suspended from reviewing due to a failed audit of this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32810341

Which part was wrong in this question?

[image: Failed audit]

Comment: The link appears to refer to a completely different review vs. the screencap.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what action(s) you took from review?

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe you are right. It says I did 'review' but did not tell me what action I did.

Answer (score 11):

As Karl Knechtel pointed out, your screenshot is of a different review than the one you linked. There are two review audits that you failed, one is the screenshotted one and the other is the linked one. The correct links to both failed review audits (the same ones linked in the review-suspension message) are https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32810341 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32879173.

In both cases, there was nothing wrong with the questions that you reviewed. They didn't require any action to be taken on them. Your review outcome for both says "Reviewed", which means you tried to take some kind of action on the question, which was inappropriate and caused you to fail the audit.

Since you didn't tell us what action(s) you tried to take from within the review queue, we can only guess.

The bottom line is that both of those were "known-good" audits, and they were valid audits. Those questions are in my area of subject-matter expertise, and there's nothing wrong with either of them that needed to be handled by a reviewer. So, trying to do anything to those questions from within a review task would cause you to fail the audit.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405788/5763564 commenting can no longer cause you to fail a review, if I understand that answer correctly.

Comment: Hmm, seems so, @Marijn. The review queues just keep getting worse. Thanks for the reference anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray What do you mean by getting worse?